# Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, locked-votes

Anyone seen this one yet?

Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited

My vote was only a few hours old. Then I realized the answer was wrong. Updated my question and went to remove the vote. Even after updating question I still have the issue.

Small issue, but frustrating.

---

#### See also:

[Vote undo window drastically reduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046)

Comment: The error message is referring to the post that you have voted upon - if I understand correctly, you asked a question, voted one of its answers up mistakenly, then edited your question.  This behavior is by design; I will update the error text to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: We will have to discuss the use case you're suggesting - the removal of cast votes on answers when the parent question is edited.  Above all, we have to prevent "gaming" of the daily rep system!

Comment: I know, its so annoying, just like 5 mins after voting I realize they're wrong, but can't change vote.

Comment: Just had this happen too. A comment, only a few minutes later, made me realise that the answer I'd voted on was wrong, and I couldn't rescind my vote. :(

Comment: "Status -by design" - if the design is not good, it should be changed.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Read my comments? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146353

Comment: I hope no one will vote me as "too old to be changed" - I'm still young enough to learn new things. ;)

Comment: Why can you change the accepted answer, but not a vote?

Comment: So considering all the upvoted answers are against this... will it ever be fixed?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Its easy to be misled by an incorrect answer that "sounds right" when you just don't know.

Sometimes the early answers that "look right" and sit at the top of the stack get over-voted.  When some genius posts a better answer you want to revoke your vote..  but you can't now.

Forget about "gaming".  Its about giving the most "points" to the best dadgam answer, and fewer points to the less-great answers.

Comment: An example of this is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281384/jquery-conditional-selector-for-table-rows/3281415#3281415

Comment: I upvoted something without testing it. Well, it did not work (and was sloppy come to think of it). I just mislead other people (left a comment at least). Sure leaves a bad taste.

Answer (score 62):

I had the opposite problem on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308432/do-try-catch-blocks-hurt-performance-when-exceptions-are-not-thrown/1308480#1308480). I downvoted the response because it seemed to me (and at least one other commenter) that it answered the wrong question. The original questioner came back and commented that the answer I downvoted actually did address the question he was asking. When I saw that comment the next day, I tried to remove the downvote but got this message. I would like to right the wrong, but can't.

Comment: Yes - I have had the same problem with questions. Went to up vote a question I had already up voted, so the up vote was removed!  Now I can't put it back - the original up vote that is...

Comment: @Stuart Helwig This happened to me too, it is quite distressing. I had to make a senseless change to the post to put my vote back. I guess I will have to pay more attention until this is fixed, as I hope it will be.

Comment: Yes, I once down-voted mr Skeet and eventually realized that I am an idiot and had misunderstood his response. Unfortunately, there was no way to remove my down-vote.

Comment: Same problem. This seems like a flaw to me.

Answer (score 40):

<sarcasm>
Unfortunately, the developers of Stackoverflow use IDEs and Editors that don't let 
you change code once you've typed it. Also, they never make mistakes or modify 
anything they've done. The concept is alien to them. So, as much as anyone might 
want this feature changed, it can't be done.
</sarcasm>

Comment: <irony>The sarcasm tag is deprecated as of Humor Templating Markup Language 5.0 ... please change it.</irony>

Comment: <depression>@dreftymac The `<irony></irony>` tag has been deprecated since 01/01/2016. Please use `<thisisaverylongtagthatyoucantrememberanywaysbutisthenewwayorwritingthenowdeprecatedtagironicallycalledirony></thisisaverylongtagthatyoucantrememberanywaysbutisthenewwayorwritingthenowdeprecatedtagironicallycalledirony>`</depression>

Answer (score 21):

+1 Change it!

It has just happened to me (again) someone downvoted and wrote a comment which I agree with (I think you should have to write a comment on downvote). I then said why they are wrong and defended my point and they agreed with me, but were unable to upvote.

https://superuser.com/questions/59692/do-facebook-group-wall-posts-appear-for-all-groups-or-only-those-you-are-a-member/59695#59695

Comment: Looks like the OP on that rephrased your answer and scored an upvote.

Comment: I guess he will also mark as answer! Annoying but nothing can be done!

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps only downvotes should be locked in quickly, to prevent gaming the system.  I do find it annoying that upvotes cannot be retracted after a more thourough review.  We all make mistakes.  And since people dish out up votes freely, as they cost nothing, it makes more sense to allow for a longer time to lock upvotes in.

Comment: Why can't they just detect when people are gaming the system by changing votes and then ban them?  Why is there a punishment for "changing vote" when there should only be a punishment for "voting negative when it competes with your answer and then changing back to neutral or positive after your answer has been accepted"?

Comment: Sometimes I quite unmaliciously downvote only to later realize my downvote was idiotic, at which point I want to, quite unmaliciously, take my downvote back but I can't.

Answer (score 11):

There's a different case, which is when the question doesn't change, but the environment does.  For instance, if I ask a question about, say, VIM, and there's an answer which is helpful for VIM 7.2, I'd like to vote it up.  When VIM 8 comes out, this answer may no longer be the best, and a new answer may take the place of the old one.  At this point, I may want to remove the previous vote to reflect that the answer is not as good as it used to be.

Answer (score 11):

The exact same thing happened to me this morning when I tried to undo an upvote on an answer. The answer itself was only 30 minutes old. I think something is seriously wonky with that right now.

Comment: It's been recently changed to lock in your vote much sooner.

Comment: Mentioned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046

Answer (score 10):

All explanations ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes/135393#135393) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/163139)) that I've seen re reason of time limit to change vote decision are about misuse of down-vote.

If there is no reason to limit **up-vote**, the limit should be removed.

Also, the games with down-vote and subsequent up-vote based on the rule, that if user undo down vote, the reputation point will be restored. 
To avoid this, the rule can be changed, that after 5 min user can undo down-vote, but the reputation point will not be restored.

These changes will allow users to freely undo their up and down-votes but still will prevent unhonest "gamers" to restore points by undoing down-votes.

Comment: As for downvoting abuse: I *assume* that even a 2 point cost would then not stop folks from doing that, as gaining a single additional upvote totally makes up for that? (I've never understood that people would even think about this tactical downvoting when posting their --late-- answer but [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) the data showed it was happening indeed.)

Answer (score 4):

I gave vote and then thought I should wait for some better responses and I immediately undid it. Later I didn't got any other answers and many people had only viewed that post. So it meant that the answerer was right. But now I can't give him vote. I can only mark it answered.

Answer (score 3):

What if you **reduced the incentive to downvote other answers** by increasing your "downvote reputation penalty" if you have an answer in that question?

For example, say the average answer for a small question earns me +30 reputation. If I'm required to pay -10 reputation for downvoting other answers in that question, I probably use my downvotes sparingly.

*"I don't care if I lose 10 reputation; he is wrong, and I know it."*

Comment: Just to be clear, if I don't have an answer in a question, I would only loose the standard `-1` reputation, to encourage constructive downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

Could the vote-locking policy be reconsidered?

The purpose of SO is to promote good answers. Honest votes help achieve this.

People make mistakes.  The time-frame within which they know enough to realize their mistake may vary greatly.  `N`-minutes (for any `N`) may not be enough.

Both the the OP question and the top voted answers here make it evident that there's a broad desire to change the current locking policy and allow users to undo their mistaken or accidental votes.

Consider the simple, and common scenario: a voter realizes he made a mistake, and he wants to undo the mistake. Assume he doesn't have an answer on the question (which can be checked) so he's not gaming anything.

***why can't he undo his mistake?***

Is there a good convincing answer to this question?

Comment: This doesn't really fit as answer here, and I fear it was already asked many times. [One](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98673/can-we-get-rid-of-locked-votes-or-have-a-longer-grace-period), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226308/allow-users-one-late-vote-change-per-day), [three](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-an-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left) and probably more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard; Indeed, it is not an answer. The alternative was to re-write it as an answer: "I feel/think that locking votes is misguided policy that should be fixed" but I felt it was too strong so I rephrased it as a question :)  this being 'meta-SO' I felt this may be appropriate. I read the other references, too. I picked this one because the Q had highest number of upvotes.  The #1 "justification" of this policy is that the policy is there to prevent gaming the system but I fear this is a fallacy (see above why).

Answer (score 2):

I posted an idea regarding this on this question: [Undo an up/down vote after a comment is left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left)

Answer (score 1):

I've had that happen with votes that were a few days old that I tried to change, but I've never tried changing a vote that was just a few hours old. I think maybe they need to extend the time for freezing votes... something like 24 hours after the last edit. If the question itself has been edited and the focus changed, old answers may no longer be valid and users may want to adjust their votes accordingly.

One other problem, which I haven't ever noticed: If the question is edited, can votes on old answers be adjusted, or does the *answer* have to be edited? If the question is modified, it would make more sense for all the answers to become "vote-modifiable" again.

Comment: If the question is modified and revoting reopens, then at least give me a notification that the question was modified so that I have an opportunity to fix it.  Once vote modification is locked on an answer, I don't think it should be unlocked unless the answer is edited by the original owner.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this discussion, I am going to "Favorite" posts I want to remember to vote on later.  I don't see any other stackexchange mechanism for easily tracking questions and I'm not yet using the "Favorites" feature.

I am forgetful - but I don't want to forget to vote - and my previous mechanism (voting while uncertain) just failed me: something looked perfect so I upvoted, I tried before the 5 minutes and couldn't get it to work, removed my upvote (not understanding the lock), and now I cannot upvote the answer (perfect, after all).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should vote for an answer unless you definitively know it's right. A few hours should be more than enough time to understand if something posted was right or wrong. You should be voting for things you **know** are correct, or at least correct in their context, don't vote for things *you think might be correct*.

Comment: One issue is that sometimes the question is edited and a previous answer is no longer the most correct, hence you may want to swap your vote to another answer.

Comment: +1 good point Ian. Put a few hours - maybe 2. Would love to see this as a 24 hr period but they may have their reasons.

Comment: Up-votes mean 'This answer is helpful', not 'this answer is correct.' Hover over the vote-up arrow to see this.

Comment: There is a time allowance after a user edits a post. I agree that things could be improved so that you can see when something you up voted has changed, but the actual time limit itself isn't too flawed IMO.

Comment: @Robert: An answer that no longer addresses a newly edited question probably *isn't* helpful.

Comment: Well an answer clearly isn't helpful if it's **incorrect** ... Unless somehow your opinion differs from mine in that respect.

Comment: OK, but how would the original poster know that, if he answered on the basis of the original question?  There's your reason for the time limit.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, that's the reason for the time limit. But since most people aren't sitting at their computer 24/7, they may not see the new edit for a while. Extending the window for revoting to at least 24 hours after the edit may be helpful.

Comment: Is this for revoting on an answer I've already submitted, to which the question has been edited? If that's the case, I don't think it's my job to monitor these questions constantly to find out if my answers need to be fine-tuned. Do I even get notified that the question was changed? If I edit my answer, then I think the revoting window can be reopened for my answer.

Comment: It may be related to time of day, i.e. the Server's day ended in-between.

Comment: It's bad enough that I am now going to get downvotes for an answer that no longer matches the question because the author edited it (which I *will* get a notification for).

Comment: You can always delete the answer, or attach a note saying **No longer relevant after edit of original question** , I know the situation sucks, but there's not too much you can do in that respect.

Comment: "You should be voting for things you know are correct" but isn't that why you're asking the question?  Its easy to be misled by an incorrect answer that "sounds right" when you just don't know.

Comment: If you don't know if a posted answer is correct, then test it and see, or don't vote on it.  Otherwise you're ruining all value of the vote system.

Comment: This happened to me after only a few minutes. I upvoted an answer then read through some other answers which convinced me that the one I upvoted actually was not correct. No I can't undo it.

Comment: @JohnFx, I have voted on questions (one today specifically) that I thought were correct (today I didn't build the requisite sql tables) and then there are comments that are entered that persuaded me that the answer was incorrect. Unable to undo :-( I hadn't even entered an answer on that question, I'm not trying to game the system!

Comment: The time frames for this have changed since july. You need to consider that the reasoning I presented here applied to different circumstances.

Comment: It's possible to be correct now and incorrect later. New versions of software might be released, better solutions might be discovered, or my priorities might change.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask a question, but the answer does not solve your problem, then the problem is not with the answer.  The supplied answers might not help you with your problem, but some other user might have the exact problem you have asked about, and there are good answers to that question.

Instead of changing your question, you need to ask a new one, so that it better reflects your problem.

Answer (score -4):

Based on all the "vote too old" feedback, I modified the text to make the timed vote locking a bit more clear:

> #### You last voted on this question
>
> #### Mar 28 at 7:55
>
> #### Your vote is now locked in
>
> #### unless this question is edited

Where "question" and "answer" are substitutions.

Also note that [the window for undo was increased to 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759) a while back.

Comment: Nice, also when memory fails me and the dialog can tell me when I actually voted!

Comment: The problem isn't in the error message; it's in the vote locking policy.

Comment: (And since April 2011, votes that have been undone in time, [are no longer locked in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373).)