# Where can I read about the question/answer ban system rethink?

Tags: support, post-ban

From what I recall, there's a project in the pipeline to redesign or replace the question/answer ban system.

This was in regard to a specific problem: users who post extremely poor quality material might entirely cease to care about their bans and their question quality, and start registering new accounts to continue posting, which means there's a threshold at which the system implodes and starts working to the opposite of the intended effect.

However, I can't remember where I read about this, nor can I find it again through searching - where can I read about this project?

I'd like to link to it in a site meta discussion where it's pertinent, and refresh my memory of what the details are.

Comment: I think this was the start of it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits

Comment: @jonsca I think that's the one. (Brad Larson's talking about the kind of issue I'm thinking of to.)

Comment: you might be interested in posts tagged se-quality-project at [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) and at [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project)

Comment: @gnat I am! Thanks, I didn't realise those tags existed.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm not going to add that link as an answer, but you are welcome to do so.

Comment: another tag worth checking is [meta-tag:anti-recidivism-system]