# What is the difference between /help/asking-rate-limited and /help/question-limited?

Tags: support, post-ban, help-center, rate-limiting

There are 2 help topics about question limiting:

- [Why have I been limited to one question per week?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-limited)
- [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

What is the difference between those?

Comment: *Repetition is the key to success.*

Comment: Looks like the same thing, from two different points of view: one is from asking questions point of view, and the other from the user's account point of view. Two roads leading to the same place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **/help/question-limited** is an [Anti-Recidivism System](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610) ([May 2014 Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2014/05/may-2014-newsletter/)) and it limits user to asking only question once per week.

  > #### Anti-Recidivism System Added
  >
  > We’ve added some new systems that deal with users who request deletion in order to evade restrictions that are placed on their accounts at the time of deletion. We log data on such accounts at time of deletion, which is then referenced should a new account from the same individual be created. If the user was suspended at the time of deletion, then the new account will inherit the remainder of the original suspension. If the user was blocked from posting questions at the time of deletion, then the recreated account will be restricted to posting only one question per week until the quality of their contributions is demonstrated. Both cases of these can be found in the moderator-accessible user history of the new account, and you can see whether a user is restricted in question frequency by looking near the question and answer block status on the user’s profile page.

  Which is later on Updated:

  > #### Update
  >
  > As of October 12th 2014, the rolling rate limits are now in place as part of the question-block system. This means, users will get more chances to write better contributions prior to being outright blocked. If you delete your account while being blocked or limited, you'll still be limited to one question per week.
- **/help/asking-rate-limited** is an introduced (Stack Exchange Quality Improvement Project) rolling rate limit  which limits user 1-7 days to post question based on performance of previous questions. Visit [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/260388) and [Breaking down question blocks - let's talk about rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/260388) for comprehensive information.

  From [September 2014 Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2014/09/september-2014-newsletter/):

  > #### Incremental Question Rate Limiting Implemented for Problem Askers
  >
  > The former question block system, which simply outright blocked users indefinitely after hitting certain thresholds of poor question asking behavior, has been replaced with a more robust system that uses an incremental set of temporary bans. It is designed to slow down question asking in accordance to the user’s performance – if they continue to post poor questions then the length and frequency of the blocks will increase accordingly. These measures are based on a lot more factors than previously examined, including average question score, time between questions asked, participation elsewhere on the site, and most importantly whether or not the user revisits their content and fixes it up.....
  >
  > Read more → [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542)
  >
  > Check out the **Help Center Article** → [Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

Visit [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/260388):

> #### Asking
>
> - Users < 125 rep, 40 minutes, network-wide
>
>   - Users limited by Anti-Recidivism System, one question per week
>   - Users limited from asking questions for 1 - 7 days based on the performance of their previous questions

Here the last one refers to `/help/asking-rate-limited` whereas second last refers to `/help/question-limited`.