# First-Post "No Action Needed" should not count to review stats

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, new-users

A few years back, the "No action needed" option [was added to the First Post review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147867/late-answers-and-first-posts-encouraging-unnecessary-actions) to prevent an overabundance of voting.

The pendulum has swung too far the other way, now, and people are just clicking 'no action needed' without actually fulfilling the purpose of the First Post review queue (to ensure that first posters get abuse-filtered, or alternatively some friendly guidance, or votes...).

I suggest that the right compromise option to this is to allow people to press "no action needed" still, but to remove the 'reward' of the stats-count for those actions, similar to the 'skip' button. You actually have to review a post in order for it to be counted toward your review stats.

Thus, the difference between the skip and no-action-needed buttons will be:

1. skip - do nothing, and leave the post in the queue
2. no-action - do nothing, and remove the post from the queue

Thus, you do not earn review badges by pressing 'no-action-needed'.

Comment: But it seems that SE will do away with the whole queue as we know it: [I recommend the existing system be scrapped, and replaced with the one described below.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/)

Comment: That's a fair amount to digest, and yes, it looks like it will remove/solve the concerns I have. Now, 6-8 weeks, or 6-8 months ;-) ?

Comment: Relatively few new posts are flaggable. The most common "real" review action for FP is voting, which has its own problems. [Voting as a review action is, and always has been, a terrible idea. I sincerely regret adding it to this queue, and solemnly pledge to do all that I can to see it removed.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277348).

Answer (score 12):

> no-action - do nothing, and remove the post from the queue

Thats incompatible - do nothing and do something in the same time. Actually, *fair* reviewer *will* review the post and, if no problems found, will click "No action needed".

Saying that *No action needed* shouldn't to count as action and therefore increment the number of reviews as you did is like saying say that "Leave open" in close vote review, or "Leave closed" in reopen votes queue, or "Approve" in suggested edits review also shouldn't count as action.

The only difference will be that one *No action needed* will complete the review alone, while all the listed action above can't complete the review alone.

So the better proposal is:

#### Require two (or even three) *No action needed* to complete the review.

but this action should still count towards the review stats.

Comment: Upvoting because I agree that multiple NAN is a good idea to complete the review, but this will also just make NAN lazy reviewers even worse, and have more opportunities to 'earn' review badges, and will make the problem worse. So, Require multiple, but still should not count towards stats.

Comment: @rolfl The same problem is also with "leave open", "leave closed", "approve", as I mentioned.