# With Triage and Help & Improvement coming up, is there still a point in making suggestions to the low-quality, first-posts and late-answers queues?

Tags: support, meta, triage, feature-request-process, help-improvement

I am not very active on StackOverflow, so I do not know very much about the current state of [Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/2127008) and [Help & Improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466/2127008), but as far as I can tell:

- They will replace or fundamentally change the low-quality, first-posts and late-answers queues.
- They will be shipped to the whole network when it’s finished (which is in [6–8 weeks™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/255554)).

Is this assumption correct? If so, am I correct that there is little point in investing time (or bounties) on creating and improving feature requests concerning the low-quality, first-posts or late-answers queues?

Comment: triage is for questions only, handling answers in current queues (LQ/FP/LA) will most likely stay as is; in particular, it's hard to imagine how triage can impact Late _Answers_ queue at all

Comment: @gnat: Are you sure? <s>Shog</s> Shogging through the snow [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/255554) writes: “Note that for brevity, I'm focused entirely on *questions* in this post - a corresponding review queue for answers should also be created, with more or less identical functionality.”

Comment: I see, you are maybe right. If stuff like triage is going to be introduced for answers, First Posts queue will likely go away

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That post is a proposal from July 2014; a lot of water passed under New York City bridges since then.

Comment: @Woodface: Sure, things may have changed but they also may have stayed the same. If you are aware of some carification that I missed, it may very well partially answer my question.

Comment: My point is that when Triage and HIQ were actually implemented, they turned out to be quite different from the specifications in the proposal. E.g., it's not a two-stage process but two separate queues with different reviewers. Also, in [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251737) Shog9 indicates that the very small sites likely won't have Triage or HIQ, hence will still have FP.