# Data explorer query request: a plot of total views vs. reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, data-explorer, views

There's a recent push to be more welcoming to beginners.  This leads me to the question: *Are people coming to Stack Exchange because of questions made by low-rep users?*  To get some data (not opinions) on this, I'm seeking a Data Explorer query which gives the following plot (I made a pen-and-paper mock up).

The plot is for an individual SE site.  A point (x,y) on the line implies "y views come from users with <=x reputation", where y is normalized.

The closest I found is [Who Brings in the Crowds?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/43336/who-brings-in-the-crowds) and [Number of Views for all posts given a specific tag and duration](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/112459/number-of-views-for-all-posts-given-a-specific-tag-and-duration).

> [image]

More specifically:

- The x-axis is reputation, and goes from 0 to the maximum reputation user (e.g. Jon Skeet) [may need a log axis].
- The y-axis is the normalized number of question views (100% includes every view of every question on the site).

My Data-Explorer-fu is not up to scratch so I can't write it myself.  So could someone *please* make this DE plot for me?  (Pretty please.)

---

I attempted to [whip this query up myself](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1205329/1484128/number-of-views-on-questions-by-users-with-up-to-a-specified-reputation).  <s>It overflows on Stack Overflow, but seems okay on other sites.</s>  But I don't know how to turn the variable `@MaxRep` into a column, and thereby create a plot from it on the website.

---

*Success!*  I made the StackExchange plot look a bit nicer using pgfplots:

[image: A plot for StackOverflow drawing using pgfplots]

Comment: Question - what do you mean by "beginners"? Also, how does rep equate to being a beginner? The reputation of a user can be impacted hugely by a post that has tons of views... and, well... the general tendency will be more views likely leads to more votes... and higher reputation. An extreme example: https://stackoverflow.com/users/126778/robert-wills

Comment: I don't really have satisfying answers to those questions.  I mostly have in mind the "beginners" who just ask their question and vanish.

Comment: Looking for something like this? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1205334#graph

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm after.  Thanks!  I'll probably edit the CSV in a spreadsheet.  (The 50% mark is 2361 reputation.)

Comment: `There's a recent push to be more welcoming to beginners.` [It's been a couple of years at the very least](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236537/lets-have-an-explicit-triage-system-for-questions-from-new-users).

Comment: Views of questions is correlated with question score and answer score and reputation. It may be that if people come for your questions, you do not remain a low rep user. If anything I would say that people come to SO because of questions made by medium rep users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to creating a graph is [choosing the right columns to output](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#graphing). [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1205334/total-question-views-by-user-reputation#graph) is a query with a linear reputation scale; it's probably more insightful to [plot the reputation on a logarithmic scale](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1205338/total-question-views-by-user-reputation-logarithmic#graph) (but you have to remember that a 3.0 on the x-axis means 10<sup>3.0</sup> = 1000 reputation):

[image]