# How far back can you edit a vote?

Tags: support, voting, edits

How far back can you change a vote?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not far enough. :(

[It's a very short time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046), not specified exactly so as to prevent gaming, but it's somewhere in the realm of 1 or 2 minutes after the post was last edited.

If you have a high enough reputation, y[ou can remove or change your vote on an old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15672/you-can-remove-votes-up-or-down-on-questions-that-you-edit) by editing it first. Jeff has stated that this is considered acceptable, but personally I would prefer we just grant this ability directly.

Comment: It seems silly to only allow high-rep users the ability to retract old votes.

Comment: and a post is cosidered edited after the question votes on a answer?

Comment: @homestead No, only after the poster (or someone with sufficient rep) edits the post with the "edit" link (next to "flag", under the post).

Comment: @Chris I agree, but Jeff seems to consider it "by design".. :(