# Why would I be told it's too late to change my vote when I have yet to cast a vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I just accepted an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/26842/can-i-trust-a-hard-drive-that-has-had-to-reallocate-sectors/26899#26899) to one of my questions on SU and wanted to throw the guy an upvote as well, but I was denied.

[alt text http://img154.imageshack.us/img154/333/20090927134158.png](http://img154.imageshack.us/img154/333/20090927134158.png)

As you can see, I haven't cast a vote yet, but I am not allowed to do so because it thinks I have already.

Comment: Have you fiddled with the vote button before?  Toggled it up and down?

Comment: @hyperslug: I don't recall, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @raven, if you did, that would explain it. This is exactly the same as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted

Comment: @raven, if the post is ever edited (as it just was), your vote capability should reset.

Answer (score 4):

You probably voted on it and removed your vote some time in the past.   The timer starts ticking as soon as you vote, even if you remove that vote before it expires.

Touching the up or down arrow means you have a very short time window to decide what your permanent vote will be:  up, down, or nothing.

Comment: what he said -- you have already voted.