# Suggested edits unlock votes on old posts

Tags: bug, voting, suggested-edits, locked-votes, gaming-the-system

**TL;DR:** Suggested edits shouldn't unlock votes on a post until they are approved.

---

Votes on posts get locked in after a certain time. The reason given for this behavior is to prevent [tactical](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) [downvoting](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/).

There are [known loopholes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48561/self-editing-undoes-vote-locks-sorta) to get past this. Since the post being edited unlocks the post's votes, a user can edit the post for the express purpose of unlocking their vote. While frowned upon, there isn't a real mechanism to prevent this, other than the reputation threshold required to edit posts (we just have to trust that users with enough reputation to do so can be trusted not to abuse this loophole).

However, it appears this loophole can be exploited through **suggested edits** also. The suggested edit doesn't even have to be approved! Thus, anybody can throw a junk edit at a question just to unlock their vote.

Comment: My first instinct while reading this was vote to close as a duplicate. However, I think perhaps you should turn this into a feature request instead. Something along the lines of not allowing a user to undo an old vote if they were the most recent edit.

Comment: The 'workaround' you propose does not apply to lower-reputation users, as they cannot "just edit" the post to unlock their vote.

Comment: @Jim, but then when I downvote due to a typo, and later realize that I could simply improve the post, then I could not undo my vote after that?

Comment: The only bug related to change a vote after editing, is in [Undone edits disappear from revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history)... Apart from that, even Jeff [suggested to do a dummy edit if needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left/21839#21839).

Comment: (And I assume [this edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/70853/revisions) was a test? If not: that was a bad edit.)

Comment: @Jim Edited the post to reflect it.

Comment: @Arjan Yes it was, sorry for the bad quality... ;)

Comment: I also rolled back [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66696/revisions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters It does! I have below 500 rep and it work for me. As I mentioned, you don't even have to wait for a mod to approve your edit before undoing your vote

Comment: @Arjan I don't get it. What was wrong about the 2nd edit you linked to?

Comment: You removed the word "not", which was there for a good reason. Also, I think using `[tag:whatever]` in your own post is already ugly if it's not intended to be clickable; editing someone else's post is just abusive editing, I feel.

Comment: I really don't feel your edit reflects what I suggested. If anything, this is now more vague and more of a duplicate.

Comment: @Jim Do you think I should rollback it? Can you edit the post for me (I not very eloquent or even coherent when writing :-( ...)

Comment: @Arjan Oh well, too bad for me...

Comment: @YatharthROCK: right, so a *suggested edit* already unlocks the vote? That I'd call a bug, it should not (in my opinion) unlock the vote until *approved*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Exactly. That's the bug part of my question (which in retrospect should probably have been in a different post to avoid it getting mixed in the slew of downvotes about to come...)

Comment: Downvoting an answer has a cost (-1 rep). Tactical downvoting means trying to keep your answer on top (to harvest the attention resulting in votes), until you are high enough to not care about the competing answer, so you can remove your downvote and regain the lost reputation point.

Comment: @YatharthROCK: That is *totally* not clear. Nowhere in your post do you say this applies to suggested edits, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But for the downvoters, the cost of 1 rep is nothing to the chance of getting boatloads of upvotes and an accept (even one of which could easily make up for 15 others)

Comment: @YatharthROCK I've edited it to make it a bug report about the suggested edits. I'm going to post a separate feature request about disallowing self-edits from unlocking votes, unless you'd like to do the same

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've made an attempt to clarify the question

Comment: @Jim No, please you do it. I'd probably mess it up like this one :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. What does `TL;DR` mean?

Comment: I've also added another workaround to the system

Comment: I'm working on the post now. TL;DR means "Too long, didn't read". It indicates a quick summary of a longer post. I stuck it there so anyone who has seen the previous versions of this question can get a quick recap of what the current version is about without having to read through the whole thing

Comment: @YatharthROCK: "Too Long; Didn't Read"; indicating a summary.

Comment: @YatharthROCK I think you've misunderstood the post you've just linked to. You *can't* change it indefinitely. It states that once a vote is unlocked, you can make exactly *one change*. So if you've downvoted, you can either *undo do the downvote* or *cast an upvote*. You cannot, however, undo a downvote *then* cast an upvote.

Comment: @Jim No, I tried. You can keep toggling between the states and it enters the system (to test, just wait a few minutes and refresh)

Comment: Did you test that on a post where your vote was previously locked? That is expected behavior on a post where you vote was not locked. If you are, in fact, correct that this works on previously locked posts, then at the very least you shouldn't use that post as a reference, since it says *the opposite* of what you are claiming.

Comment: @Jim No, I meant for unlocked posts. Made it clearer

Comment: That's true, and not relevant to this issue. You can change your vote as many times as you'd like before it is locked.

Comment: I just tried it on [one of my questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/should-i-use-all-the-or-all-of-the/) on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com). I could upvote an answer, remove the vote, upvote it again, remove it ad infinitum.

Comment: So does that mean this only applies to downvotes?

Comment: @Jim I could upvote again _after_ the question was locked. Can you reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably wasn't waiting enough. Trying again.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this as a duplicate of that particular question - they are clearly different.

Comment: @Jim That scares me as I can't see the number of close votes (I need 150 more rep). This is NOT a dupe.

Comment: @YatharthROCK There are 4 votes to close it as a dupe of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/request-change-in-behaviour-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited)

Comment: @Jim Can't you cast a "unclose" or "open" vote then?

Comment: So are 5 votes needed to close a question?

Comment: @YatharthROCK 5 votes are needed. Five votes are also needed to reopen, but can only be cast on a closed question. If this question doesn't get closed in a certain time frame, those four votes will begin to expire.

Comment: @Jim Really (the expire thing)? What about needing more votes the more popular the thing is? I heard they used something similar for deletion votes. But what with Reddit-LOLfest and other popular-but-off-topic questions, it might not be such a great idea...

Comment: And the upvote thing I was talking about, I couldn't reproduce it. I probably wasn't waiting enough for the time windows to close...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/167443

Comment: Votes should never be locked in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use your workaround to undo my accidental down-vote, but it didn't work for me.
I've edited https://stackoverflow.com/a/4328971/52277, but I still wasn't able to change my vote.

It is not reproducible.

That's pity, because I hoped, that this "bug" will allow to workaround very annoying "vote-lock" restriction.

Comment: You can only do the toggling thing if the post has not already been locked. I removed the section as it did not seem relevant to locked posts.

Comment: If you try it on another post, I'm confident it'll work.

Comment: I just tried it on [one of my questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81184/should-i-use-all-the-or-all-of-the/) on [English](http://english.stackexchange.com). I could upvote an answer, remove the vote, upvote it again, remove it ad infinitum.

Comment: So does that mean this only applies to downvotes?

Comment: @YatharthROCK I rejected your edit. If you're just testing things, please use [the official sandbox question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/) instead of "real" posts. There will be cases where that's not feasible (in which case, explain in a comment or the "edit summary" field, I guess), but this shouldn't be one of them, assuming you're testing the behavior this question is about.

Comment: @PopularDemand Oh, OK. Didn't know about that. Thanks for telling me :)

Comment: What should I do to get a 5-digit rep like you, i.e., what stuff should I do a lot to get me there?

Comment: No problem, it's hard to find the sandbox when you're new.