# Locked votes can be changed by editing a post

Tags: discussion, edits, locked-votes, change-vote

This is somewhat related to this question: 
[Self editing undoes vote locks.. sorta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48561/self-editing-undoes-vote-locks-sorta)

But relates more to the senario that when a vote has been locked for a particular post, the user can edit the post (by maybe just adding new line or something) and subsequently the user can then change the vote the that was previously locked.

It's a strange feature but essentially renders the functionality of locking votes useless for users with enough points to edit posts.

Comment: Meh, this is known and I would be surprised if it isn't dismissed as status-by-design. Is it really that big a deal?

Comment: Nah it's not that big of I deal, and I'm not trying to ruffle any feathers I just wanted to let them know incase they hadn't considered that senario.

Comment: This has been known and understood for a long time now.

Comment: bummer that you felt like this question needed a down-vote, I'm just trying to call attention to a behavior I've observed.

Comment: The downvote(s) just means people don't think it's strange or problematic. I consider it a side bonus of having 2K rep. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the following advice is given by [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21839/187824):

> If you feel so strongly that you've made a terrible mistake with your vote, **earn 2k rep, edit the post, then change your vote**.

Though he does not advice to perform too minor edit. So they know this scenario.

Comment: Does his post really count? He's got -40 ATM and 95% of votes are down.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes because it is advised by [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), co-founder of Stack Exchange. Downvotes means people don't agree with that.

Comment: @Jan People are probably not disagreeing with the ability to change your vote by editing, but rather with the fact that this is the *only* way to change your vote after it is locked in.

Comment: @CodyGray true, that

Answer (score 4):

This is functionality the system actually encourages. Consider the two cases where it could be used:

1. Changing your vote on somebody elses posts.

   If you really care about your vote enough to change somebody else's post (hopefully improving it), also possibly giving up your anonymity, then knock yourself out. I've done this myself on posts I've downvoted. If I can think of a way to fix them myself so they don't actually need the downvote and the user doesn't come along and do it, I think eventually edit it myself and reverse my vote.

   Keep in mind that this does not allow you to case a second or third vote for something, it only allows you control over the one you have. The vote lock system prevents fickle toggling of votes for no good reason. A post changed wither for better or worse might be a good reason. It also leaves a paper trail so it is unlikely to be used by revenge downvoters or other underhanded schemes.
2. Allowing vote redos on your own posts.

   Again, why would this be a bad thing. If your post got downvoted and you want people to be able to change their votes, fix your post! Once it's edited, they have a chance to review and possibly cast a different vote.