# The strange case of Dr. Upvoter and Mr. Edit

Tags: discussion, edits, voting

Not a rant, just curiosity :)

[In this question from **Jan 2013**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273707/in-java-application-trace-all-methods-in-eclipse-debug), I answered normally (not my best answer ever, but still worth reading I guess, and it gained one upvote).

Another answer was marked as accepted. Nothing strange then.

Except for the fact that **today**, the user who has written the accepted answer edited both the question and the answers (all the edits was a one-character "fake" edit), and removed the upvote from my answer.

No downvote, just upvote removal... that is strange, because when someone really doesn't like an answer, usually he/she downvotes it. Amazed by this curious gravedigging, I've run the [Have We Met?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met) query on SEDE, and the result was that we never met. I don't really care when I got some random downvote, but this "upvote-removal" has been so weird that led me to ask this question:

Is fake-editing other answers / questions to be able to alter the vote casted to them legit? Should this kind of behavior be flagged for Moderator attention?

As a side-question: any clue on what happened? I know I can ask him, and I probably will, but I'm more interested in your (hopefully) funny comments right now...

Comment: Related : [Locked votes can be changed by editing a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186784/187824)

Comment: Maybe they were at the vote cap and thought that by un-upvoting they would get an extra vote today (which I don't believe is true)

Comment: I would say it's bad behaviour to make a minor edit just to remove your upvote, but what do you expect from the moderator? To re-upvote your answer?

Comment: @hims056 comment answered the main question... if Jeff said this is legit, it simply is :) BTW the side question is still open; I'll invite him here to explain, just for the records :)

Comment: @RichardTingle nice guess, twisted enough :D I see your comment, raise it "he clicked by mistake" :)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's one of the sock puppets.

Comment: The irony of this last edit amuses me.

Answer (score 10):

I think reverting votes is not the issue here, making extremely trivial edits *is*.

No matter what your motivation for editing is – earning reputation/badge, reverting your vote, and/or you just like 'em posts nice and tidy – the thing that matters the most is that **your edit should be (somewhat) substantive**.

I think most of us would agree that edits that

- replaces a single lowercase letter to uppercase.
- removes a single instance of bold formatting
- removes a single pair of double quotes

are extremely trivial.

If someone is still unconvinced of the triviality of the edit(s), consider:

- the age of the post(s): the mentioned question is a little more than 6 months old
- the traffic of the question: 173 views up until the time of writing

It's fairly safe to say that the question and its answers are relatively old and relatively unimportant to the general audience. If one intends to bump up a question like this, he needs to have a very good reason to do so (such as making a substantive/substantial improvement). I don't think the aforementioned edits constitute a good reason for bumping that old question.

Having >2k reputation gives you the privilege to make any edit you want to any post. However, it doesn't mean you should make very trivial edits (regardless of what your motivation is). It's not healthy for the system.

Comment: I love your gravatar.

Answer (score -12):

I can up/down vote any question/answer anytime and it's my choice to revert my decision. It also happened to me on my answer/question – people down/up vote it, and then they revert their decision. Reverting votes is not a big deal, but **FREEDOM OF THOUGHT**, I think, *is* a big deal.

Comment: We're more curious, you can of course vote as you see fit

Comment: The question is: Is it appropriate to perform too minor/fake edit just to revert our vote?

Comment: I'm actually more interested in why you did it (that is the side question)... be cool, I won't downvote you (here nor in SO), I'm just curious.

Comment: and, of course, you can't revert your vote at any time... that's why you had to abuse the editing system and make fake edits.

Comment: I feel downvoting this is counter productive, we do want an answer after all

Comment: I m cool and i m not worried about downvotes as well... and this is the fact i told in my answer,

Comment: @zzzz But you must have thought the answer was good, then later changed your mind. The thing Andrea wants to know is why you changed your mind so that they can improve their answer

Comment: actually i think i can not explain it properly, at that time this thing just came to my mind and i done that, you can name it what you like... unethical, non sense or Mischief... that is your choice :)

Comment: O, well that’s disappointing. It is an answer at least

Comment: Yes it is... but i did not down vote it... i just removed my vote.

Comment: did you think "hey my answer was accepted, and I upvoted other answers, but no-one upvoted back... screw this, I'm going to un-upvote" ?

Comment: and removal or vote is not liked with any thing or any of my downvote... but i also agree that **We Never Met** as you told

Comment: @hayd i think it was not in my mind... i don't  use stack for vote count or reputation i just use it to get some help and if i can help some one in the shape of an answer,

Comment: @zzzz then what possible reasoning was there to fake edit and un-upvote, it certainly had nothing to do with getting help or answering. Inarguably it was "poor form".

Comment: So you just decided to revert upvotes just like that out of a whim? They are suddenly not helpful anymore? I find such logic twisted in many ways.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You may say this....

Comment: The fact that you are digressing this way is generating hype and incrementing our curiosity :D Are you telling us that it will remain unsatisfied ? :( C'mon!

Comment: @AndreaLigios [FREEDOM OF THOUGHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_thought) was quite enough to remove curiosity :)

Comment: Bah... nobody is saying you are not free, just arguing why you freely decided that way with your free Free Will...

Comment: I am free to walk out into the street and sing the complete ABBA collection backwards while hopping on one leg. I think why would still be a fair question

Comment: I wrote in answer/comments what all was in my mind... now its up to you if you agree with my answer or not... that's all... I will request you all to remember me in you prayers ... thank you :)

Comment: Ahah top trolling :) Ok, feel free to change your mind and post here all the dirtiest details, I'm gonna close it here... so long and thanks for all the fish ;)

Comment: Well, at least you are not [oscillating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166098/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That is *exactly* what this answer and the comments on it remind me of `:D`

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and I thought *this* was weird :D +1, Oscillation definitely made my day ^^

Comment: So now our new answers to everything: "Caching. Always caching." "6-8 weeks." "Oscillation." "Freedom of thought." `:P`

Comment: @Doorknob ahahahhahahaha :D

Comment: @RichardTingle The "why" is *obvious* in the case of AᗺBA.