# Non-existing vote too old to be changed

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, voting, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Vote too old to be changed”… but I haven’t voted!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted)

I was in doubt whether to upvote or downvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564980/building-a-comma-separated-list/1565042#1565042).  I quickly undid both my up- and downvotes.  But now that I'm sure I'd like to upvote, I cannot vote at all.  The errror is:

```
Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss)
```

But there is no vote registered for it, so how can the vote be too old?

Comment: Why vote before reading through a post and making sure either way?

Comment: Read through your post and found the dupe that describes the same behaviour. It's not a flippant choice when picking out a responsible/relevant dupe.

Comment: Agreed and apologies, I did not see the "Possible Duplicate" at the top of the post, on stackoverflow the duplicate link is in the Closed row.

Answer (score 1):

The previous up or downvote registered as a vote. Therefore until the answer is edited you will not be able to vote. It has nothing to do with the amount of votes the answer has, but rather with whether you did or did not vote on it already. Removing the vote doesn't neccessarily allow you to vote again, and from your explanation it probably triggered one of the checks not to allow you to vote again.

Bottom line: **Be sure before casting your vote**

Comment: I can't be sure before casting my vote. There is no such thing as "first time right" in software development.  Anyway, if what you say is correct, the error message is misleading.

Comment: That sentence makes no sense to me. How can you not be sure before casting a vote. The idea of voting is to vote up **the correct answer** not to vote at a whim? Test solution, if it works, vote, if it doesn't. Don't. Either that or you already know it's the right answer, vote it up.

Comment: I am never 100% sure whether something is correct, and I'm open to change my mind later.  I can also make mistakes during testing.  Finding right answers in software development is an iterative process.

Comment: @Andomar, likewise *another* later answer could actually indicate my earlier vote was kind of wrong. However, if you read the other related questions then maybe Diago's bottom line should read "Sadly, people have been abusing the votes, which have let to very strict rules. Be sure before casting your vote."

Comment: The damage done by this rule seems rather huge to me; it leaves me without an option to correct myself, making my worst calls permanent.  I would pay rep to correct my earlier mistakes.  There has to be a better solution than one that flies in the face of common sense.  People who think they're "100% sure" about anything don't know enough about the problem.