# I'm getting "Your vote is too old to be changed..." for a vote I made less than 5 minutes ago

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, locked-votes

I'm trying to remove one of my upvotes for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990395/in-c-whats-the-best-way-to-spread-a-single-line-string-literal-across-multiple), but I'm getting the "Your vote is too old to be changed..." message. I made the vote less than 5 minutes ago.

Edit: It seems that this is because the answer was deleted. So the bug probably isn't that I *got* the error, but that I got the *wrong* error.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **The below is no longer true and [was relaxed to 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/152859).**

---

That's correct -- the vote lock in period is less than 5 minutes. Significantly less.

The second you cast a vote, the clock starts ticking.

Once locked in, you can only change your vote if the underlying post is edited.

edit: I don't think deletion of the post will matter in this case; the same rules apply.

Comment: I'm curious why this is. Isn't it reasonable for someone to change their mind within the span of a few minutes?

Comment: @Matthew: the lock-in time was decreased dramatically to discourage "strategic" voting--i.e. voting someone down not because you think the answer is bad, but because you want your answer to be ranked higher so that you can get more votes. people would do this, then later remove their downvote (to get back the rep they lost for casting the downvote). by decreasing the lock-in time from days to minutes, you at least have to live with the consequences if you do that. (is that pretty much correct, jeff?)

Comment: Ah, ok. That sounds reasonable.

Comment: almost -- the deeper problem is that undoing your vote leaves no audit trail. And we can't expose vote history for what I hope are *extremely obvious* reasons. :)

Comment: @Jeff - one feature of the vote lock in that I've hit is that if an upvote is removed within the lock in window, one can then no longer upvote or downvote that post. Is that intentional behaviour. I've hit this when voting for an answer, then rethinking whether the answer is actually correct and wanting to do some double checking (like running the code through a compiler for example). Once I've confirmed that I do indeed want to upvote, I've lost the ability.

Comment: Preventing people from voting on threads they are involved in would be a better solution.

Comment: U62, no, that's a bad idea. It has been discussed before, and declined.