# Electorate legend

Tags: feature-request, wording, electorate-badge

The current text is: "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

I think it should read "Voted on 600 **posts** and 25% or more of total votes are on questions", which is what I believe was meant (understanding post as "question or answer")

Comment: Nope, it is 600 questions

Comment: 'Questions' only are the type of 'post' that are being cumulatively measured for that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, it means what it says. See [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording).

Comment: I see... it's two conditions then

Comment: And it says what it means!

Comment: I understand now, I got confused by the "two conditions in one sentence" paraphernalia