# Electorate badge, is it working?

Tags: support, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording)

On SO I have 855 total votes.
Im positive that by atleast my 600 vote mark i was only voting for questions.

so a minimum of 255 question votes

255/855 ~ 30% of total votes are on questions.

Did something change or is it broken? This is my only chance to ever get gold flair! don't take it away from me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's working, just keep voting on questions. You need to vote on 600 questions **and** have 25% of your total votes on questions.

Comment: i feel i meet both those criterion. is my math wrong?

Comment: @Galen, again, you need to vote on 600 **questions**

Comment: ok i was assuming it meant 600 votes 1/4 had to be on questions.

Comment: This answer finally clarified it for me.  The definition is confusing...  I interpreted it as being you must vote on 600 "things" (other than comments, i.e., question/answer groups) and that 25% of these must be on the actual questions.  So this would qualify: (150 votes on questions)/(600 total votes on other than comments) = 0.25.  Glad I figured it out finally...