# Possible problem with Electorate badge

Tags: bug, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Electorate badge, is it working?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48588/electorate-badge-is-it-working)
>   [Electorate badge rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/electorate-badge-rules)

I have over 1000 votes.  The last 100 votes were almost all votes to questions.  Since I hit 600 votes, most of the votes have been for questions.  So, I should have at least 250 question votes by now.  That would give the required 25%.  Could this be a possible bug with this badge?

Comment: I hope you haven't been going around just voting up questions so you can get a badge. tut tut :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have voted on 600 questions and that 600 votes is 25% of your total votes.  Having "at least 250" isn't enough :-)