# Wording change on Electorate badge

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording)

It seems like the change to the Electorate badge wording decided in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording), is inaccurate.

> **Electorate** - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

If you vote on 600 questions than 100% of votes **are** questions.

I think this should read:

> Voted 600 times and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to MSO, Grillz! Unfortunately, you have misunderstood the badge. Your proposed wording would award the badge to someone who upvoted 200 questions and 400 answers; that doesn't happen.

See [the community-generated badge info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge/67399#67399).

(That said, the very fact that you misunderstood is itself good evidence that the wording needs to be changed; just not the way you proposed.)

Comment: Thanks for this - didn't know that page existed.

Comment: when is that page you so lovingly created going to be a part of the official FAQ.  I don't know how many times I or others have posted a link to it?

Comment: @Barry, only a mod can add the `[faq]` tag to a question, so... whenever one of them feels like it.

Comment: fair enough. Maybe they'll do it one day. I mean, it has only been viewed 700 times and upvoted numerous times.... ;-)