# Electorate badge question

Tags: support, questions, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarify Electorate badge wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I have 697+ ,11- votes. And I am sure more than 25% of them are on questions.

Why still I don't have it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you sure to say that you have got 25% more of them on questions?

The badge calculation works this way, You must have at least 600 votes for questions, and your ratio of answer votes to question votes must be 3:1 or lower.

You will eventually get the badge at some point in future. Dont worry about it so early, keep continuing to upvote. I got them when I had around 1054 upvotes. :))

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the badge specification.

Comment: What point is it to have a mark that doesn't work?  if the vote is 600 with %25 answers as soon as someone reaches that it should award a badge.

Answer (score 0):

Click the review option on the menu (if you have it) and it will let you know your total votes, and the percentage of question-to-answer votes you have, to see what the percentage is exactly.