# The Electorate badge's description is unclear

Tags: discussion, electorate-badge

I was recently awarded the Electorate badge, so I took a look at its description:

> Electorate: Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

It sounds, at first glance, like the system is awarding 25% of question votes which are votes on questions. What?

Comment: Related: [Clarify Electorate badge wording](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording)

Comment: This has been discussed a dozen times already, and the text you're seeing is the __already-fixed__ version. If you just read it carefully, it's actually quite clear. (And how does something "sound" at a "glance"?) That said, I did write [an extended description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/131713) in the long badge list, and congrats on the gold.

Comment: I'm confused how people get confused by this, but my suggestion is to reformat the sentence as follows: "[Voted on *600 questions*] **and**  [25% or more of *total votes* are on questions]."

Comment: It's **total** votes - votes on both questions and answers.

Comment: @PopularDemand, Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more clear?

> **Electorate**: 25-100% of total votes are on 600+ questions.

Comment: Can't we make this as the badge's description since many gets confused (Including me :P)