# Canceling an upvote on an answer delay may be too short

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

I'm sometimes having some debates with guys around a given question in stackoverflow, and I realise the answer I upvoted previously is not the one I should have. The problem is that I sometimes realise it 7-10 minutes afterwards, and then it's not possible to cancel the 1st upvote.

what is the underlying intention in this? Couldn't be the delay 10 minutes?

Comment: Vote after realized! Or wait for edit. :)

Comment: The 2nd upvote is not the problem, I also want to cancel the 1st upvote

Comment: Second upvote? AFAIK we can cast only one vote per post. Either upvote or downvote.

Comment: there are 2 upvotes for 2 answers. I want to cancel the 1st one but it is too late (10 minutes)

Comment: The best solution here is to exercise more discretion before you vote. Sometimes it happens you misvote anyway, of course; but just be more careful.

Comment: the delay is really short. 5 minutes, a coworker comes to ask you a question and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

The [timeout limit for changing votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits) is a known feature and designed feature, and as for the reason for it Jeff addressed that in comments on his answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/im-getting-your-vote-is-too-old-to-be-changed-for-a-vote-i-made-less-than).

Now there isn't a problem for voting more than one answer that you think is good. The "best" answer is accepted, and there can only be one; however you can up vote all the answers you think are good so don't feel the need to retract just because a "better" answer came in.

If you choose to upvote a question and later regret your decision because you realize it's wrong in some way, then leave a comment. The author may address your concern in a way you didn't consider before or may make an edit. Once a post is edited, then you can change your vote.

Finally in regards to the exact time for the timeout, you know... it was changed to 10 minutes, according to [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphys_law) from then on out, it would only be the 11<sup>th</sup> minute you realized you didn't want to do that up vote. ;)

Comment: No, that's definitely different 5 minutes than 10 mimutes. In my case there are not 2 good answers, really only one should have been upvoted

Comment: Also worth noting, the grace period for changing a vote is the same grace period for editing before a new revision is recorded. If one changes, the other really should follow, and it would be very problematic if the editing grace period was any longer than it is.

Comment: @Sebas - no problem, then my 3rd paragraph applies. Comment and ask for the owner of that answer to change what is wrong to make it a good answer worthy of an up vote.