# "Last voted" date never updates after you change your vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, change-vote, locked-votes

Once, I voted on an answer. 20 minutes later, the answer was edited, and I realized I erred on my vote. After changing my vote, I realized I erred again, but I knew it was too late. Nevertheless, I felt like clicking it anyway, and learned something bizarre.

[image: Temporal anomalies have a way of finding me]

According to the white text, I did not vote after the answer was edited. No, I *travelled 20 minutes into the past and cast a new vote then*.

The time should reflect when I actually last voted, if it is going to state 'last voted'. An alternative would be to just remove "last".

<sub>Also, it's really hard to report and tag these kind of things when [you don't even know what to call them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51176/messages-notifications-warnings-are-they-different-or-all-the-same-which-one).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that did this checking [is now gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373), so this shouldn't be an issue any longer.