# "Your vote is now locked" warning always tells me I voted 11 minutes ago

Tags: bug, locked-votes

I accidentally downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14250342/1608072) (mostly due to the fact both arrows are too close together and easily missed on touchscreen devices) and then upvoted it back.

Today I just noticed that this answer is still downvoted by me, as if I hadn't corrected it in the first place. I tried upvoting it again, and after refreshing the page, it shows no effect.

The strangest thing is that when I try to unvote, a box appears saying "**You last voted on this answer 11 minutes ago**".

I haven't touched this answer since *not just 11 minutes ago*, but *a few hours*.

### Numbers out of sync

Three hours later, the numbers are still out of sync. My downvote is registered from 19 hours ago in my profile, but the dialog box always reports the frozen amount of "11 minutes ago".

[image: Reputation box]
[image]

### Update

Today (13/01) I was able to unvote the answer, so the glitch is gone. I'm not sure if it's been fixed or if the system just eventually unlocked my vote.

[image]

### On a side note

What does the -1 mean in my reputation box? Does that mean for every downvote I cast, I lose reputation myself?

Comment: Huh. This is opposite to an issue [that was fixed a long time ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53201/last-voted-date-never-updates-after-you-change-your-vote). Curious. Also to answer your minor question, downvoting answers will take 1 reputation to perform, yes.

Comment: For the record, downvoting questions does not cost you any reputation. But as Grace said, downvoting answers do.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know downvoting answers cost reputation.

Comment: Now that some more time has passed: are the two numbers still out of sync? (So: does your reputation overview still claim the last vote happened about 17 hours ago, and the error dialog 2 hours?) And I assume that everywhere you write "question" you mean "answer"?

Comment: @Arjan ops, I meant "answer". Fixed. The error dialog always display fixed 11 minutes, though. I'll add to the OP.

Comment: Is your system clock set ok, with the correct time zone too? (Maybe the [Network Login Troubleshooting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) can help validate that.) If so, maybe change the title to *"Your vote is now locked" warning always tells me I voted 11 minutes ago?* (and then in the body make clear it's about a specific post)?

Comment: (Oh, looking at the Ajax response, I guess the message is really sent from the server as is. So, the system clock will have no effect on the message, I guess. I guess changing the title will get more attention to the problem.)

Comment: @Arjan it really wasn't on my end. I had the same problem on both my PC and my tablet. But yesterday I was able to unvote it and then upvote the answer, so the glitch is gone. Not sure if it's been fixed or the system just eventually unlocked my vote.

Comment: @Arjan changed title. Sounds clearer.