# My lack of a vote is now locked in?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

I voted an answer up, then unvoted it up beacuse I realized it was actually wrong, then waited 10 minutes, and after reading some comments decided to upvote it again. I can't. Why not?

Comment: Geez, the fact that this comes up so often almost makes it seem like this behavior is user-unfriendly...

Comment: @jon you know what else is user unfriendly? all the voting and gaming exploit around unlimited vote undo windows. Sucks that we have to lock the door on our house, but there are criminals.

Comment: @Jeff - does the "undoing a vote counts as voting" make it less gameable (serious question)? Please don't give up on usability.

Comment: This doesn't look like a dupe of that question... that person actually had a vote in place and then tried to revoke it. I had **NO VOTE** on that question, but it was locked anyway.

Comment: @Mark It should've been a dupe of ["Vote too old to be changed"... but I haven't voted!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted), but it is a dupe nonetheless

Comment: @Jon If revoking a vote didn't count then people could downvote, wait 4m59s, unvote, immediately downvote, and repeat as often as they want

Comment: @Michael - to what end?

Comment: @Jon It lets them vote and then undo the vote later; the same problem vote locking solved in the first place. They can use a sockpuppet to upvote their answer temporarily, or downvote a competing answer temporarily, and then take the votes back later to hide it

Comment: @Michael - I don't object to vote locking, I think that's a good thing. I don't understand why "unvoting" counts as a vote. Many users undo their downvote and then (either immediately or later) try to upvote. But you can't, because undoing your downvote counted as a vote.

Comment: @JonB Right; I'm trying to explain how allowing vote undoing is equivalent to not having vote locking at all -- you can trivially script it so your vote is never locked in by undoing and redoing it right before it would be locked

Comment: @Michael - I see what you're saying. You can also just edit a post. My opinion is that the loss of usability is too great for the magnitude of the problem being solved.

Comment: @Jon Sure, but editing requires considerable reputation; 1-rep users can do the vote lock dodging. I don't like it either, it seems like there must be some way to at least allow votes retracted in the first ~10 seconds or so to not have counted at all, but this is the reason retracted votes still count against you, and the reason these posts always get [status-bydesign]