# Not allowed to vote on post which I haven't voted on

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited “problem”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)

I voted on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142453/a-problem-with-pointer-to-pointeranytype-var-in-c/4142487#4142487) and then cancled my vote (within the allowed time span), an hour later I want to vote and get the vote too old error. This post currently  **doesn't** have a vote from me (neither up nor down). As much as I think the whole vote locking in idea is wrong this is even wronger.
[image: post in question]

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360, not 6250.