# Why can't I re-vote after having unvoted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Vote too old to be changed”… but I haven't voted!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted)

I thought if I clear my vote, I could re-vote later.

Apparently not.  I upvoted, cancelled the upvote, then tried to re-upvote 8 minutes later.

No-can-do, says Mr. Orange box.

[image]

[Y](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgbntWU7pG8#t=1m26s)?

Comment: yeah I had this too. Is this intended or a bug? I hope it will be fixed.

Comment: As shown in the duplicate: this has meanwhile been fixed.