# Upvote doesn't register

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

I clicked the upvote button on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467255/adverts-in-active-wall-paper) question, and the vote count did not increase! Oh well. Then I clicked the upvote button again, to undo my upvote, but a message box told me that I had voted on the question 8 minutes ago! This was wrong, but oh well. It's just an upvote.

So I posted my answer, and refreshed the page. But then I saw this![image: WTF!]

Impossible! Unless, of course, someone downvoted the question! But I had pressed the upvote button almost a second after loading the page, and the question was only viewed 12 times!

Was there a mystical force of darkness that interfered with my question, or did someone just happen to click the downvote button just as I upvoted?

Comment: *"I had pressed the upvote button almost a second after loading the page"* — you're a fast reader then...!

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, I am a fast reader, but in this case that didn't have much to do with this. Sometimes, I just click the upvote button to look at the shiny orange thing. Most of the time, I click the button again-no harm done, right? But in this case, my upvote could not be retracted. Mystery ensues...

Comment: Very well, then maybe my edit to retag from `[bug]` to `[support]` was wrong. (To me, it convinced me that your recollection of the events could not be as you described it... My bad?) What time does the message give you now, when clicking it again? (The question was posted at 20:34.57Z.)

Comment: It says that I voted on it 1 hour ago.

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp Well, there's harm done in that after 5 minutes your canceled vote is locked in and you can't vote on the post at all, so if you make a habit of this you'll never be able to vote on anything

Comment: @Michael, [not anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373): *"if there is no lit up/down vote arrow on a post, you may vote on it*"!

Comment: Try _not_ clicking on buttons that initiate actions you don't plan on taking. The more click happy you get the greater your chances of breaking the software or getting less than optimal results. Don't click for the shiny orange thing (which also sends rep to the OP and is available for other visitors to see) if you plan on undoing it (which has to go undo those actions). Read the question and make an informed vote. Once.

Comment: Hmmm, @JavaAndCSharp, "one hour" is not helping us here. I guess we need to wait until it shows a specific date and time, to see if maybe that claims to be *before* the question was even posted...

Comment: @Arjan Oh, excellent

Comment: To the downvoters, I ask: why?

Comment: @JavaAndCSharp - votes here are different than SO, dont take any offence. People are just indicating they dont agree with the question or dont think its helpful for this site...

Comment: Now that some time has passed, the error message will show the exact date and time you voted. What does it say?

Comment: @Arjan: It says "You last voted on this question on Dec 11 at 20:45..." I explicitly remember unclicking the button immediately afterwards voting. The mystery remains...

Comment: So, the question was posted at 20:34.57. The screenshot shows "asked 19 minutes ago", so was created around 20:53. At that time, 20:45 was indeed about "8 minutes ago". But then: you created that screenshot *after* you posted [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467255/adverts-in-active-wall-paper/8467371#8467371) which I guess took you at least 3 minutes to write, while you description says you tried to revoke *before* even writing that answer?

Comment: @Arjan: Correct. Bleh, a big hairy mess. I'm of the opinion that voters should be allowed to revert votes. Then again, I have a bad habit of clicking on things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I can see the up/down vote counts, I can tell you it has been downvoted (1 upvote, 1 downvote).

Probably more of a coincidence than of a mystical force ;)