# Remove vote locking for high Privilege users

Tags: feature-request, voting

I am requesting that the vote-locking mechanism be turned off for users with high Privilege levels.  It seems absurd to say that one is a "Trusted User" and not allow him vote reversals.

There are often legitimate reasons to reverse a vote as new information or understanding comes to light, and I should *not* have to edit the answer just to unlock my vote.  It is inappropriate to leave comments or critique in the body of the answer, so the edit would usually have to be trivial.

Comment: "There are often legitimate reasons to reverse a vote as new information or understanding comes to light" Shouldn't that information be edited into the answer **anyway**?

Comment: @user137537 I don't think so.  I do not believe it is correct to edit someone's answer to include my critique!  I would rather leave a comment saying "this fails in cases x,y,z"

Comment: I mean... edited into the answer by its author.

Comment: @user137537 - operating undercover today? ;)

Comment: I support this proposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree. Vote locking was [introduced to prevent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22776/160166) [tactical downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18373/160166) — where you downvote a competing answer immediately so that it gets "pushed" below yours in the sorting and then remove the downvote when you're sufficiently ahead. Tactical downvoting is still a problem on SO and implementing this change would put the power of tactical downvoting in the hands of the very few that are above 20k, greatly worsening the problem.

> There are often legitimate reasons to reverse a vote as new information or understanding comes to light, and I should not have to edit the answer just to unlock my vote

If there are legitimate reasons to reverse a downvote, then just ask the answerer to make an edit so that you can change your vote. I'm sure they'd be happy to oblige. If you'd like to reverse an upvote, then make the edit and remove it and let them know why you've removed so that they can make the necessary changes to get back that upvote. If you'd like to be discreet about it, make the edit and come back a few days later to reverse your upvote.

**"Trusted user"** is often misunderstood by many to mean *"we trust you to not to indulge in bad behaviour, so here are some relaxed rules for you"*. It might help to sit back and take a pragmatic look at it and realize that all it ever means is *"good job, here are some more tools to clean up the muck!"*.

Comment: You've been at this longer than I have, and I trust your judgement.  Accepted.  But they really should call it *janitor* rather than  *trusted user*...