# Count comments as 'post is edited' for vote changing

Tags: feature-request

People make mistakes. We are humans - just like you, forgive us.
I know it's been discussed here before, but I suggest a different approach.

Sometimes I up/down vote an answer because I believe it's right/wrong and the question asker should look/not look at it.

When someone posts an incorrect answer and gets voted up, some other user who detects this mistake will add a comment, explaining why this answer is not to be followed. Then I read that comment and understand that I have made a mistake as well following the answer and upvoting it (same goes for the opposite - down-voted correct answer).

My request - Include comments as a 'post edited' status - because sometimes even the original answerer posted a comment.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left

Answer (score 4):

I'll agree with this simply as a more logical way to get my damn votes back whenever I make a mistake in voting. It doesn't seem logical to have to go and force an edit on a post just so I can retrieve the vote back.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the vote lock almost useless, unless it lets you undo your vote only under ceratin conditions:

- Doesn't count your own comments (the voter).
- Only unlock if there's a new comment (after your vote) with enough upvotes (2 upvotes?)

I vote a lot, and I have made a few mistakes I couldn't undo, but I don't think it's important enough or happens often enough to change the system.

Comment: I didn't think that the threat of strategic downvoting was large enough to institute such a draconian lock in the first place, but they went ahead and changed it then.

Comment: "this makes the vote lock almost useless", which is a good thing. If i add a comment explaining why I am changing my mind, I should be able to unvote.