# Another "downvote-response" proposal: allow user to cancel a downvote if he leaves a comment to the answer

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Simple, clear, useful.  If you left a comment *before* you casted a down-vote, you can cancel it without editing the question.

Inspired by litb's [proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/add-downvote-reason-and-downvote-response-comments) on that matter.

Comment: ...But if you were lucid enough to leave a comment with your downvote in the first place, doesn't that mean that it was a well-though-out downvote, and unlikely to need cancelling unless the answer is improved?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, well, it doesn't mean that.  Proof: see the comment above.

Comment: @Pavel Shved: I disagree with your implication that my comment wasn't well thought out.

Comment: Well, you can't fix stupid.

Comment: Sure you can, you just need an appropriate castration tool.

Comment: @Robert, @womble: Wow, tough room! @Pavel: -1.

Comment: +1'ed it. Also, i think it's important that once you made use of the "downvote-reason" comment by retracting your downvote, you cannot remove that comment anymore.

Comment: @Pavel, I have changed my question to be a "bug report" now, though. So you may put your proposal as answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Great idea.  I unconsciously stopped downvoting after the downvote-lock window was introduced.  It's just too easy to miss some detail that totally changes the question.

The downvote dialogue was one of the great learning experiences of Stack Overflow.  You'd think-- this is WRONG and downvote it.  Then someone else would explain that in fact, you were wrong.  This kind of useful dialogue has all but disappeared.

Your suggestion would require a special kind of comment that can only be added with a downvote.  Otherwise you could comment "+1 excellent idea" to explain a downvote :)