# why can't i change my decision on downvote

Tags: discussion, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mistaken downvote cannot be undone after matter is being clarified by the answerer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/mistaken-downvote-cannot-be-undone-after-matter-is-being-clarified-by-the-answere)

If I press the upvote or downvote by mistake and later I realize that I want to cancel the effect and bring it back to what it was before, then I don't find option to do it.

It just happened today; I downvoted instead of giving it an upvote. Later I thought by giving it a downvote will cancel the effect of upvote but nothing. Can someone throw some light on this behavior of voting?

Comment: You can ask the OP to edit the question then you'll be able to undo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vote gets "locked in" after 5 minutes. After that, you can only change it if the post gets edited.

See also this question for more info:

> [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited-problem)