# Have downvotes cost more, to be refunded when a comment on that question/answer gets an upvote

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, down-votes

This is an idea I have seen around, but I have not seen a feature request for it, so here it is.

Downvotes that have no comments are frustrating and difficult to manage.  This is a way to help improve that:

- Have a downvote initially cost more to cast for the downvoter (5 points for example)
- When a comment (from the downvoter) on the downvoted question/answer gets an upvote, you get your points back.

  - All points (ie all 5) could be refunded or just up till the traditional -1 that is in place now (ie 4 points refunded).

This would encourage good comments and downvotes for real reasons.  (Because comments for questions/answers that are bias related will not get the upvotes as readily.)

This could/should be limited to non-subjective tags.  (ie tags where a downvote just because you "don't like it" is not appropriate.)

Comment: this has been discussed before... multiple times.

Comment: Is there a denied feature request for this?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased has been [status-planned] for quite a while though

Comment: kind of dupe-ish: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-a-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left and indeed [status-declined]

Comment: While about downvoting, nether of those requests discuss having a downvote cost more then refunding some/all of the points when a comment gets an upvote.  (Though the comments of the first does discuss this idea, it is not the focus of the question.)

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30066/require-comments-when-downvoting

Comment: Related true, but does not bring reputation into the equation

Comment: LOL, two downvotes because there are questions that discuss comments and downvoting?  Read the request, if there is another that is the same then post it.  Otherwise, why the downvotes?

Comment: Requiring a comment to explain a downvote is a bad bad bad idea, as discussed in the URLs listed above. It doesn't matter what the reputations are, it's still bad. Changing the value of downvotes has been discussed and is ostensibly in the pipeline, so we'll just have to wait and see for that.

Comment: @Vaccano: Sure, your feature request is just another way for encouraging people to explain their downvotes. This is what has been done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes, and I don't think much more will be implemented any time soon. Nothing personal. Just what I feel from the other discussions that have been going on.

Comment: Don't think so highly of yourself. Downvotes on feature requests mean "I don't like it".

Comment: @Æther: I disagree.  A comment can often make a downvote be thought out better.  Bringing rep into it and requiring an upvote on the comment would prevent the stupid comments (like "aslkjfda")

Comment: @random: true, downvotes on a feature requests are just so (I don't like it indications).  However, for Stack Overflow that does not hold true.  (Which is why I put this request out there.)  I a bit to my request about it only applying to non subjective tags.

Answer (score 6):

If this happens, I won't downvote anymore... and the system needs downvotes.

Comment: I would have downvoted you if I knew I would get my rep back

Comment: +1, I completely agree (no, this isn't to hide a downvote without losing rep, what are you talking about?)