# Still cannot cancel my downvote, even though post has been edited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, voting, locked-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I change my vote if the  post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr)

I downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573159/java-check-boxes-in-a-jcombobox/1579848#1579848) because the original revision was poorly formatted.

The author then edited it, to fix the formatting.

I still cannot cancel my downvote.

Note: I am **not** trying to change my downvote to an upvote, just cancel the downvote.  This has always worked for me in the past.

Could it be to do with the fact that the author edited it less than 5 minutes after originally posting it, so the edit does not appear in the history?

---

**Update**: I was able to work around this by editing the answer myself.

Comment: I disagree with the 'status-bydesign' tag. It is not by design, it's a side effect of another part of the design. i.e. a bug.  And one that is probably easy to fix.

Comment: We need a "status-appealed" tag.

Comment: This is basically the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr, I think

Comment: @Jonik, You're right.  That makes this question a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is likely correct. Since there is no revision history, it can't tell that the post has actually been revised.

Comment: If so then I would imagine it should be easily fixable - update the last-modified timestamp (assuming there is one) but do not update the revision history.  Alternatively if votes have been cast since it was posted, treat it as a revision even if within the time limit.

Comment: It is specifically set the way it is because they felt it was not fair to posters who edit their posts in quick time to be punished by being thrown down the sort order (when thinks were ranked that way). Sure you can go in and change this and change that, but I doubt you are going to get much traction on that since this 5 minute "bug" is incredibly minor.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that the edit window for the first edit (5 minutes) is less than the window allowed for changing your vote.  If these two values were brought into alignment this scenario would no longer be possible.

So would it be possible to extend the window for changing a vote to 5 minutes after the original posting time?  This also largely addresses the "the vote change window is so @$@#$@ short" problem.

Comment: Agreed. There's a q specifically about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr
(although "status-bydesign", predictably)