# When a user changes his answer within the 5 minute interval, your time to change a vote is not extended

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, change-vote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I change my vote if the  post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr)

I had down-voted somebody for a very short, unhelpful answer.

After about 5 minutes I came back to see that he had improved his answer.  I attempted to change my vote, but found that the my vote was "too old to be changed."

I looked at the age of the question and it said "Answered 6 minutes ago."

Shouldn't this scenario allow me to change my vote?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr

Comment: Hrm, I searched and didn't find a dupe.  I guess I just didn't know what to search for.  Anyways, maybe this deserves a revisit?

Comment: *If* this was a matter of posting a short unhelpful answer just to get a slot in the upper region of the answers, then this still deserves the downvote, if you'd ask me...

Comment: don't worry, I made the same mistake (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26254/still-cannot-cancel-my-downvote-even-though-post-has-been-edited-closed)  That's how I spotted the dupe.  The automatic "related questions" search is optimized for SO, it doesn't work quite so well on meta.

Answer (score 3):

This has been reported before, and Jeff tagged it as `status-bydesign`.  This is unfortunate because it is awkward for whoever posted the erroneous answer.  Do you fix it quickly (meaning the downvoter cannot cancel their vote) or leave it for 5 minutes (attracting more downvotes?)

Answer (score 0):

If the edit happens in the first five minutes, then it counts as being originally written then, and you won't get a chance at a revote.

Jeff has just changed the vote timer to five minutes to coincide with the edit timer, as per his [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759).