# Anonymity of downvotes has a loophole

Tags: discussion, voting, anonymous

I spent some time trying to help the OP on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723782/how-can-i-pass-an-int-value-as-the-linktext-for-and-actionlink/10723854#10723854) this morning.  He evidently didn't like my answer,  and gave me a downvote.  How do I know?  Well, when I deleted my answer, his rep immediately went back up by 1.

Now, I don't much care about the particulars of this question/answer (or my rep), but it seems to me that this is a potentially significant hole in maintaining the anonymity of voting.  Obviously, this hole has only been possible recently -- ever since rep changes have become reflected instantly.

Also, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128074/are-votes-really-anonymous) is very similar, but doesn't take into account the ramifications of the insta-changes to rep that led to this scenario.

Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Hey, interesting find! I guess this is now possible because the rep recalc is instant (if I understood the changes right)

Comment: What reasonable way is there to "fix" this?

Comment: I noticed this a couple of weeks ago and kind of shrugged. Unless you've got everyone's rep memorized, if your suspicions about who downvoted you are wrong, you'll be watching the wrong user and you'll miss the change.

Comment: There have always been loopholes like this, so personally I don't think this new version is anything special.  With that said, I've seen things get nasty when they're exploited.  It would be nice if there were some way to avoid this entirely, but it would probably involve rep update delays on all rep-related actions, which I don't expect to happen.

Comment: @Ben, whoops, you're right.  Assumed without thinking.

Comment: (By the way, if you'd undeleted that answer before posting to Meta, you'd probably have a few upvotes by now. /me taps side of nose)

Comment: @BenBrocka - upvotes are only kept if the post score is 3+ and over 60 days old.

Comment: O.k. the OP got 6 downvotes, are you happy now? `:)`

Comment: @Ben where did anyone mention up-votes? The question above is talking about a down-vote that gets reversed because the answer was deleted. If I down-vote an answer, I lose -1, if that person wisely deletes their answer, I gain +1. If that person is watching closely (e.g. I might be on their radar because I commented on why I down-voted), they could see that I was the one who down-voted. While I am personally against anonymous down-voting in the first place, I do appreciate that it is valuable to a lot of people, and this can threaten that anonymity to some degree.

Comment: @AaronBertrand upvotes were included in the original title

Comment: Ok, sorry guys, I do not typically review the entire revision history of a question before commenting. Will try to do that in the future. :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, it is a loophole of sorts - but it requires that you

1. Already suspect a user or users of down-voting you
2. Assume that nothing else is going on that might affect their reputation

You can strengthen #2 considerably by deleting and undeleting *repeatedly* - however, this also requires you to be able to predict when the recalc will take place. It *isn't* actually instantaneous (yes, reputation is kept mostly up-to-date, but the recalc that happens in response to post deletion is queued and executed after the deletion, usually several minutes later). And this unpredictability could probably be *increased* if necessary - IMHO, simply adding a bit more uncertainty into the system with respect to timing would probably suffice to make this a non-issue. [As yoda notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133433/anonymity-of-downvotes-and-upvotes-has-a-loophole/133434#133434), there are already ways to accumulate evidence of down-voting if you have someone specific in mind.

That said, this does bother me a bit. A dedicated user with a vendetta could confirm his target much more readily now than in the past. We'll want to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thanks, terrific analysis.

Comment: The question this brings to my mind is whether the last digit of rep is significant and could be dropped.  Is there really a difference between a rep of 815, 811, and 819?
Obviously, this would be a huge change that I don't think this loophole would justify.  I just remember as a teacher grading homework on a 10-point scale to avoid meaningless debates over what was a two-point mistake vs. a one-point mistake.

Comment: @John: well, 811 is a magical number, so you'd always want to display that... ;-P But yeah, an interesting idea. Note that this already happens in a lot of places once you have a few thousand points.

Comment: Ah, we don't call them dedicated users with a vendetta anymore, we call them moderators now.

Comment: You could always automate the watching with a few API calls too - watch everyone who comments on or also answers the questions you answer and you'd probably spot a good chunk of the downvoters.

Comment: I agree, I was thinking that a sufficient delay instead of instant gratification could offset this quite a bit.

Comment: I cannot find yoda anywhere in the question's comments.

Comment: @fedorqui It was not a comment but a now deleted answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuvnR.png

Comment: Randomized fuzzying of rep by a couple points when displayed on site a la reddit would probably be just as effective against the type of people who would actually do this. Then again, the actual consequences of a few of people using rep to add some vague evidence to their already existing "suspicions" aren't exactly dire.

Answer (score 17):

Now this is interesting to me...

I happened to get a random downvote shortly after you posted this, and decided I'd spend a minute looking into this loophole again. I identified a suspect and deleted the answer, then wandered over to that user's rep page, where I soon saw this:

[image]

which surprised me, because that seems to be lasting proof positive of a downvote.

***However***, I tried later to reproduce this effect by deleting the same post, and saw no such entry, so it seems that this was just a hiccup. It would definitely have been a bug had it been reproducible.

Comment: That shouldn't be there; you aren't supposed to see reputation from deleted posts on anyone else's profile, as far as I know.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. If you're seeing it on *your own* profile after something you down-voted was deleted, that's by-design; you shouldn't see it on someone else's rep tab.

Comment: @Shog9 I can see the rep tab of Jacques. `+70  3 mins ago  7 events...`

Comment: @ajax333221: yeah, you're able to see up-votes received, but you shouldn't be able to see down-votes (given or retracted).

Comment: @Shog: It was definitely on the other person's rep page, with the name of the post on which I had _recieved_ the vote. There's only one vote on that post. I undeleted it since I was just testing this loophole (and I don't think the vote was deserved). Would you like me to email the dirty details to team@?

Comment: @Shog: Well, I just tried it again, to be sure, with the same post, and I _do not_ see the results I've reported here. I see no entry at all in the other user's rep page. This is as expected and as it should be. I guess it was just a hiccup.

Comment: Yeah, if you encounter this again, please send details (and screenshots, lots of screenshots) to team@. Thanks!

Comment: Still, odd! I downvoted that very same post now (and will change that into an upvote after our little testing). Care to delete it again and peek [into my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84237/arjan)?

Comment: @Arjan: will do.

Comment: Ok, I see it's deleted but have not yet gotten my -1 back. That will take at most 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I can see the removed now.

Comment: @Arjan: I've got the 2 rep back, and I see no entry on your rep page. It seems this was really just a fluke. Going to undelete unless you'd like me to wait.

Comment: Nope, waiting doesn't seem it will help us :-) Next test: see if I can revoke my downvote due to your deleting/undeleting. If not, then I'll make a dummy edit.

Comment: You checked both sorted by time and post, I assume?

Comment: @Arjan: Well, no, just by time, since that's the view in which I saw the entry previously.

Comment: @Arjan: The upvote wasn't necessary but I do appreciate it (not having a -1 post in my list). Thanks for helping check this out, too!

Comment: Okay, your deleting/undeleting does not count as an edit. Not what we were investigating, but at least I learned something today ;-)

Comment: +1 for the testing documented in the above comments.

Comment: @Jacques, any chance you were also playing with the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your own reputation overview? Of course, that setting should only affect what you are seeing on *your* reputation overview, but who knows...

Comment: @Arjan: No, I set it when it came out and haven't touched it since.

Comment: This same thing happened to me at one point. I was able to view the reputation history of any profile as if it was mine, all downvotes showed up. I thought it was kinda bad that such voting was public, but didn't know it was a bug. But it looks like it was one of those bugs that fix themselves.