# I can see others' rep change from removed downvotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, anonymous

I am a mod on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/). Today I looked at a certain user's reputation page, only to see that they had received a point back for a removed downvote on a post that I had recently deleted. This was visible to another mod on the site and remained so even after I refreshed the page a few minutes later. I should not be able to see this as it lets me know who the user downvoted, even if only after the post has been deleted.

Screenshot and some discussion is available here (mod only, for the user's privacy): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8932508#8932508

**Update**: Per the comments, these are visible to regular users as well.

Comment: Does this always happen, or was it just this once?

Comment: @Servy I've never noticed it before.

Comment: This looks like it's new (I've never noticed it before either) and persistent (looking through user reputation histories, I can see when they got +1 back on deleted posts going back several weeks).

Comment: @BilltheLizard Does it look like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/KcuFf.png

Comment: @Mysticial Yes (except on my screen the removed posts are highlighted in red).

Comment: @BilltheLizard Interesting. It even links through for me. And I'm not a mod. Is there any way I can tell you which user this is without posting publicly? (if you weren't able to figure it out already)

Comment: @Mysticial DM'ing me on Twitter would probably be the quickest way.  Let me see if I can find a heavy downvoter on a site where I'm not a mod.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Damn, I don't have a twitter account... I just checked, and those downvotes still appear when logged out. They don't link through since logged out is not 10k.

Comment: @Mysticial You can post a comment here and immediately delete. Bill can check the deleted comments.

Comment: @DoubleAA Good idea. Done. Bill, check the deleted comments.

Comment: Oh yeah, good thinking.  :)  @Mysticial Yeah, I see that user downvoted four answers on that post.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That's weird... I only see 3. Probably since I'm not mod.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I volunteer to be a _heavy downvoter on a site where you're not a mod_: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=reputation In logged-out mode this shows my downvotes on removed questions - see eg Apr 4 and Apr 3, if that would be some 10Ker, they'd even could click through links I guess to get to DVed posts

Comment: @gnat Yes, I can see three removed downvotes on those days.  You're right, a 10k user would even be able to click through and see exactly what answers you downvoted.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Q.E.D. anonymity of votes has a loophole

Comment: Granted it's not a _huge_ whole. Deleted posts are usually ones where downvotes aren't so controversial anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's true.  And while it's easy for me to get from your profile to things you've downvoted, it's still hard for me to get from my profile to people who have downvoted me, so the hole is effectively one-way.  I'll still wager it gets closed soon.

Comment: @gnat I'm a non-mod 10k P.SE user, and you're right - I can easily see which posts you've downvoted from your rep history after they've been deleted :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Bill just reproduced it [using my rep tab at Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176154/mod-can-see-rep-change-from-removed-downvotes?noredirect=1#comment528791_176154 "details in few comments above") - and I reproduced it too, by looking at it in logged-out mode

Comment: @Rachel you would cry if you could see _[all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155762/165773 "quote source")_ -1s over there. :) "I downvote quite frequently and rep points I loose for doing this feel like an "investment" into site quality..."

Comment: @gnat We're looking into it.

Comment: @gnat I do cry over all the -1s over there, just probably not in the way you think :) I still stop by fairly regularly to check out the Newest Questions, Recently Deleted/Closed 10k lists, or run [some Data.SE queries](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3140/1130) to see if things look like they're changing at all, so I'm still relatively up-to-date on what goes on at Programmers.

Comment: Further info: not _all_ deleted posts which I've downvoted are visible, for some reason: Looking at my rep: [Today while logged in](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FQtBn.png); [Today as anonymous](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ivvZT.png); [Another day while logged in](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0iW5r.png); [That same day anonymously](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8bDui.png).

Comment: brb, suspending all 10K+ non mods on Programmers so they won't have a chance to see my DVs.

Comment: @Rachel wonder how your "cry list" accounts for [cross-posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is strictly frowned upon...'") (I just flagged and DVed two), questions posted to circumvent SO ban and questions successfully migrated to other sites?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this; it was reported [once before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133433/anonymity-of-downvotes-has-a-loophole/133440#133440), but no one could reproduce it then. Thanks to the efforts of the folks in the comments here, we've done better this time around.

Starting with the next build, no one who isn't the owner of the profile being viewed (or employed by Stack Exchange) will see the reputation returned from down-votes when a post is deleted.

Comment: No problem :) ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What changed between then and now that we figured it out?

Comment: So do we get any cookies?

Comment: You'd have gotten meta rep if you'd posted an answer, @Mysticial... (meta rep is sorta like cookies, except less tasty and also not edible or particularly useful in any way)

Comment: The problem was pretty sensitive to the time of the deletion, so just having another year probably helped, @DoubleAA

Comment: @Mysticial I managed to get myself 4 badges :)

Comment: I can report that the original place I saw this no longer has the issue. Success!

Comment: fix verified: looking at [my Programmers rep tab](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=reputation) in logged out mode, `+1`s for Apr 3 and 4 I've seen yesterday aren't displayed there anymore. Interesting that these aren't displayed in *logged in* mode either - `+1`s of deleted DVed answers seem to be totally gone away, even when I am logged in. Wonder if this is intentional? I even toggled on/off "
show removed posts" to make sure I have it on - still, yesterday `+1`s aren't there anymore

Comment: hmm ... currently I can't see the returned rep in my _own_ profile (on SO). Intention or maybe an overshooting fix?

Comment: @kleopatra as far as I can tell, this is a bug; see: [“show removed posts” checkbox stopped working for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176255/165773)

Comment: @gnat thanks for the pointer and your post: that's exactly what I'm experiencing