# "show removed posts" checkbox stopped working for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, reputation-history

I expected the feature to work as specified here:

- [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614/165773)

> ...In order to show removed posts, you need to make sure the checkbox all the way at the bottom is checked.
>
> [image: show removed posts]

Yesterday, that worked just fine. For example, my [reputation tab at Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=reputation) used to show me votes on posts removed on Apr 3 and 4.

Today, this is not the case anymore, as shown at below screen shot. Apr 3 events do not display `+1` that has been shown yesterday for deleted post.

> [image]

To make sure that it's not something else, I also checked a couple of recently deleted questions having answers with my downvotes - none of these are reflected in my rep history tab (details for SE developers - 10K only Programmers links I checked: [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/66997/31260), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26573/31260), [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/539/31260), [4](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12833/31260), [5](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/41136/31260)).

---

It looks like a side effect of the fix for recently reported bug: votes on removed posts became hidden for everyone, **including myself**.

- [I can see others' rep change from removed downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176154/165773)

Comment: That's what I immediately thought too when seeing your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was my bug from yesterday, we intentionally started hiding those votes from *other* users but owners were not properly special cased.  A fix is building out now to remedy this.

Comment: fix verified: [they're back](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7EMTf.png "screen shot")! Well done, thanks

Comment: ...(as an ex-tester) I also verified that [yesterday bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176154/165773) didn't leak through back again: in logged out mode, my [meta-tag:reputation-history] doesn't show removed posts; these are invisible to _others_, just as it should be

Comment: @gnat - excellent, sorry for FUBARing that!

Comment: @NickCraver I don't think a small mistake like that qualifies as "[FUBAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_slang_terms#FUBAR)" :) But thanks for fixing it.