# Why downvote's reputation changes -1 not showing in user profile in summary view?

Tags: support, reputation

Today I recently downvoted an answer and received -1 in reputation changes. But when I tried to see my user profile and I noticed that in my reputation list their is no listing of -1.

As if we got upvote on question/answer its reputation changes is listed in user profile same for getting downvote on our question/answer.

But why it didn't show the listing when we downvote someone other users answer?

- Is it a bug?

**Edit**

Now I knows that when we downvote any answer it is listed when we tick `show removed posts`.

But when we see other users this feature is not present. Yeah this is for making the privacy of other users.

So my question is **Moderator** also can't view who have downvoted the answer or they can view?

Comment: Scroll down and check the "show removed posts" box.

Comment: @Mysticial see edited question.

Comment: @Naruto - For your latest edit see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128077/187824) (specially first paragraph).

Comment: @hims056 Thanks. :) I edited this question to lift the ban. Anyways thanks. :)

Comment: @Naruto - Do you have asking ban on Meta?

Comment: @Naruto - Do you have any deleted question which were on topic? Then flag for moderator's attention and ask them to undelete it for you. And improve it.

Comment: @hims056 I don't remember how many are there. But I knows that they are deleted. How can I flag for moderator's attention to undelete them?

Comment: @Naruto - Simply flag this question and ask them politely. For more you may refer [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824) once again. :)

Comment: @hims056 Thanks for being co-operating. I will try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To see reputation changes, you may have to scroll to the bottom of the reputation page and select "show removed posts".

> Also when we try to view someone else's profile there is no "show removed posts" box, so how can we know that this user has downvoted which answer?

You can't - other users' votes are their own business. There [was a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176154/i-can-see-others-rep-change-from-removed-downvotes) that exposed some down-votes, but it was recently fixed.

Comment: So because of that reason should my question get downvote? Is their any reason for downvoting if user don't know about this all settings?

Comment: Please delete your answer I want to delete my question. It didn't allow me to delete.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That's not how it works. When a question has received an upvoted answer, it cannot be deleted. Don't feel too disheartened though, [voting works differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @DannyBeckett I am totally agreed with you, but is there any reason to just downvote the question if someone doesn't understand the question.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Please don't throw around baseless accusations... Most of the users on meta will up/down-vote something here because they feel it is a worthwhile or unhelpful/unclear/generally disagreed-with question or answer. I'm personally disinclined to believe that you've had enough experience here to authoritatively say that.

Comment: Please click the link in my previous comment and read the section it jumps to. People don't "not read the question and just downvote"; that's not how it works. I, myself, downvoted your question. The reason being that it's a subject which has been address countless times over, and which you could have found the answer to by simply searching.

Comment: @Nightfirecat So because of that I want to delete my question? But I can't delete it..:(

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? It serves as additional reference to the material for the future.

Comment: @Nightfirecat If you are saying `It serves as additional reference to the material for the future`. So why people think that this question is of no use?

Comment: Because it's redundant. From the perspective of someone who is looking for the answer, it's helpful to have redundant copies of it (hence the duplicate system we have in place). From the perspective of those of us who are used to researching (emphasis on the *searching*) before asking questions, it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Naruto Could you consider accepting this answer? You'd get two of those rep points back... :)

Comment: @Naruto Sorry, I'm not going to delete my answer. It's information for future users. I'd contact SE and ask them to lift your question ban - it's a decent question that fell prey to the inaccuracies of voting on Meta.