# Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, edits, grace-period

**Please do not close this as a duplicate unless you can remove the “status-completed” tag from the [original report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701) (because it’s obviously not been completed).**

Steps to reproduce:

- Have someone post an answer.
- Downvote the answer.
- Have the someone edit the answer within the initial 5 minutes of the answer’s existence.
- Try to undo the downvote **more than 10 minutes later.**

You cannot undo the downvote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It has been mentioned before that edits within the first five minutes *do not count as edits at all*. They are overwritten in the DB, and they literally never existed.

Perhaps the easy solution then is to amend that to **edits within the first five minutes *on posts with no votes***.

Answer (score 21):

Buggy By Design™.

Answer (score 5):

Well have you read Jeff's answer to the not a duplicate?

> I am relaxing the vote undo window to 5 minutes to coincide with the editing grace window

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759)

Therefore, if you retract the vote within the 5 minute grace period for edits, it can be removed, however, once that period is over, it is locked. So you 100% right. You can't remove the vote 10 minutes later.

This will most likely be flagged [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Why are you answering here only to reiterate a description of the bug? It’s still a bug.

Comment: @Timwi Because it's only a bug to you. As far as Jeff and the team is concerned it is by design, and you claimed in your post it was never fixed. It was. The time to rescind your vote was increased.

Comment: You can use `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]`, `<kbd>` is not the right way to indicate that it's a tag. ;)

Comment: @Diago that's not the point though. The point is that if you make a vote and the post is edited outside at 4:59 you cannot undo your down vote. If it's edited at 5:01 you can undo your down vote. Why would it ever make sense to allow the down vote to be rescinded because it was edited by a margin of two seconds? That just is illogical.

Answer (score 4):

It has been mentioned before that edits within the first five minutes *do not count as edits at all*. They are overwritten in the DB, and they literally never existed.

For this reason there is no way to determine that a post has been edited after the comment was written.

If you feel it absolutely necessary to change your vote, (and you have the necessary reputation) you can edit the post (modify nothing) and then reverse your vote.

Comment: ① It’s still a bug, for frickin’s sake! ② What if I don’t happen to have exorbitant rep like that? ③ Even if I did, why the frickin mickey should I have to make a pointless edit?!

Comment: @Timwi: you could always wait until after the 5 minute grace window to cast your vote in the first place.  I agree with you and I think this needs to be changed.  However, it's been raised many times and I just can't see it happening.

Comment: @Timwi I did not say that I don't consider it a bug. I said that there is no way to determine if the situation you described applies, this means that without adding extra infrastructure to the `comment` or the `post` object, they won't be able to fix it.

Comment: @devinb: Now you’ve not only described the bug, but also a possible fix for it! :-)

Comment: @Timwi Every feature request needs to be discussed in terms of it's costs and its benefits. In this case, the detriments of futzing with the DB schema most likely outweigh the difficulties of a situation which has a viable work-around already.

Comment: @devinb: What viable work-around? Nobody has mentioned any work-around that works for users with less than 3k rep, i.e. the vast majority.

Comment: @Timwi, Alright then flag for mod attention if you feel like it. Then the moderator will edit the post for you.

Comment: @Timwi upvoted your first comment because of those fancy numbers :)