# Changing votes for an answer, which has been "edited" in the grace period

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, grace-period

I upvoted an answer, and remained on the page and read a few more answers, while noticing that the user that I originally upvoted made several edits. I later noticed something from one of the edits that made me want to remove my upvote, but I got the message: "You last voted on this message 6 minutes ago.  Your vote is now locked unless the answer is edited."

I noticed that no edits were indicated, so they must have taken place during the grace period.

This was not a case of me rushing or misreading, the answer originally posted was fine.  An edit was made during the grace period.  I went back 6 minutes after I upvoted, saw something that I didn't approve of appended to the original answer and wanted to change my vote, but couldn't.

To clarify, I **understand** that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign);  I am **NOT** trying to report a bug. I am requesting that a feature be implemented such that this situation can be resolved without having to resort to making a fake-edit and a following rollback.

*Potential Solution:*
***Perhaps votes that occur during the grace period should simply not be locked-in.***

Comment: Vote locking should be killed entirely.

Comment: Related: [Hidden edits in the first 5 minutes don't unlock votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122500/hidden-edits-in-the-first-5-minutes-dont-unlock-votes?rq=1) and [Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin) and [Unlock votes if post is edited during the grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168553/unlock-votes-if-post-is-edited-during-the-grace-period?rq=1) and dozens more

Comment: @CodesInChaos I would say that is a troublesome duplicate because it was presented as a bug and then [status-bydesigned] whereas this is a feature request which cannot be [status-bydesign]

Comment: Obviously, this is a common complaint and the only change that has been made (back in 2011) is to prevent vote locking for 5 minutes to account for the grace period.  But it means you need to watch all recently edited posts you vote on for 5 minutes to ensure it isn't changed.

Comment: @SteveP. if you feel that strongly about it, there's nothing to stop you (it isn't encouraged, but is somewhat accepted).  However, it is a gigantic calling card that you voted on the post (depending on the quality of the edit) and may lead to false (or true) accusations of downvoting and/or revenge voting.

Comment: Have you commented on the answer to explain your current problem with it? Perhaps the answerer will agree.

Comment: @RyanFrame It ended up getting fixed anyway, but I noticed the issue and wanted to see if something could be done about it.

Comment: @Random re:duplicates; both those are presented as bugs (even though they are not really) and so are rightly tagged as status-bydesign. Whereas this is a feature request

Comment: With regards the latest edit "Perhaps the grace period for changing votes on answers should not start until after the grace period for changing answers ends." that would just give a 10 minute grace period to change votes. It just delays the problem; if I vote, you grace-edit then I come back in an hour the same problem exists

Comment: @RichardTingle Fair enough.  I'm being tired and stupid.

Comment: @RichardTingle Perhaps votes that occur during the grace period should simply not be locked-in (edited).

Comment: @SteveP. Now that sounds like a plan!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87196/allow-to-change-vote-when-question-has-been-edited-inside-5-minute-window