# Couldn't remove downvote after the poster corrected his answer because the vote is locked in

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin)

I downvoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10006302/626273) after the second revision. The user corrected the mistake, but his correction seem to have counted still into the second revision.

After the correction I wanted to remove my downvote, but wasn't allowed to, because it was locked in.

Luckily the answerer edited his post again so actually I have removed my downvote, but I still see this as a problem.

- On the one side I like this feature, when I am editing my own posts. I can fix some spelling mistakes shortly after posting, without being that a revision on its own.
- On the other side I don't like that feature in the voting case.
- I also understand that the votes are locked in to prevent gaming.

**So my idea:**

Would it be possible to change the revision counting a bit? Ok, not the counting but the ability to change my vote after a not counted change of the post.

Maybe remove all vote locks on a post after each change of a post, even if that change is not counted as a new revision.

Comment: I think that dup link is describing the same behaviour (there for the initial post, here for the second revision). Anyway I understand why this happens and do not report this as a bug, I am making a feature request to change this.

Comment: thats why you have to think again before downvote someone's answer.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees The user didn't change his mind on the same version, but after a revision.

Comment: @Alenanno but i think before downvoting you have to give chance to the user for correction.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees That is up to everyone. There are users who comment before down-voting and others that just down-vote. If there is wrong info in the answer, it's your right to down-vote. I don't see a problem in that regard.

Comment: @Alenanno yes, you are rite in your manner and i am in my manner. But sometimes i have seen that some beginr asked a question wrongly and downvotes if not getting exect answer, so i think every down vote has to be rechecked by the cumunity