# Downvoted answer, answer was edited, can't withdraw my downvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin)

Here's the question:

[How to get the name of current function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130504/how-to-get-the-name-of-current-function/10130542)

Here's the specific answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130542/189950

Initially, the answer was written as:

```
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

I downvoted this answer because it was wrong -- the stack frame parameter being `1` was incorrect; since it was the current method, the value shoud have been `0`.   It has since been edited, and now shows the line:

```
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name);
```

I would like to withdraw my downvote now, but when I look at the answer, it:

1. Does not appear that there were any edits (I dispute this)
2. It is now showing the code using the argument `0`

Am I going crazy?  Did this edit not actually happen?  Or is SO being overzealous about eliding edits, and thus preventing me from reacting to this edit properly?

Comment: It was probably edited within the 5 min. grace period. So it doesn't get recorded.

Comment: Sure -- but shoudn't I be able to react to that?  Should I not be able to say, "Oh, good, that's why I downvoted.  Now that it's been corrected, I would like to withdraw that downvote!" ?

Comment: Thanks lunboks!  I think it's still a bug, but at least I have recourse.