# Can't cancel vote if edited in five minute window

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, down-votes, grace-period

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/cannot-retract-downvote-if-post-has-been-edited-within-first-5-minutes-of-postin)

I recently saw a question where because of the lack of the relevant source code needed to solve the problem I decided to give it a down-vote, but thought that if the OP corrects the issue I would cancel my down-vote (someone had already left a comment to the effect that the OP should edit their question).

A few minutes later I came back and saw that the OP edited their question  and tried to cancel my vote but was stopped with the message along the lines of

> You last voted on this question ... Your vote is now locked in unless
>   the post is edited

I'm assuming the reason that the system hadn't picked up on the edit is because it was done withing the five minute grace period where the edit isn't tracked for revisions.

I know that as a workaround I can just edit the post and add some white space to remove my vote, but I don't think a suggested edit from a under 2k user just adding white space would be approved (or at least it shouldn't).

Just a note, I did see that there were several questions here related to canceling a vote, but I don't think this is a duplicate as here the user did edit their post.

Comment: Just don't be so quick with your downvote. Give the OP at least the grace period. That said, are you sure the post is utterly perfect now and nothing could be improved?

Comment: The votes are locked by design, so it's not really a bug.

Comment: @Bart In hindsight I agree, and in general I actually very rarely down-vote. That said in this case I think I could find what to improve in the post, but unless this is by design I think it's a bug.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ my impression was that the design is until the post is edited, which it was.