# Can't undo my vote, even after the answer I voted on was editing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, down-votes

I voted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299728/how-can-i-combine-two-hashmap-objects-of-same-type-in-java/4299737#4299737) down, and left a comment explaining why.  The guy changed the answer, and left a comment saying that he had, so I tried to remove the downvote, but it tells me my vote is locked in.  Why?

Comment: Looks like he [edited within the 5 minute grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr), and it you came back a while after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He edited within the 5 minute grace period, so that's not a formal edit from our perspective.

Comment: But it was an edit based on my comment.  Because he was fast and I wasn't quite fast enough, that downvote is forever un-cancellable?  Weird.

Comment: @Paul, not forever: one bogus edit (even an edit by yourself) is all that is needed to allow for removing or changing the vote again.

Comment: I really don't like this either. For editing yourself, he has to edit it, you have to go through moderators or have enough reputation. Why not to say that, if he edited it after any comment, you can change your vote? It makes much more sense.

Comment: This isn't worked as design.  It's worked as implemented.  Your answer explains why the implementation led to the bug, not that this behavior was actually correct or desirable.  And this behavior is neither correct nor desirable.  If the business logic is too tricky to get "furtive" edits to unlock votes but this is acceptable because there's enough ways around votes being locked in, then fine, but you should edit your answer to explain this.