# How about making the downvote during grace period behavior more clear?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, grace-period

This is a suggestion for a minor user interface tweak. Could SO make the behavior described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote#139950) (answer edited after downvote but within the grace period still locks downvote) a bit more clear in the user interface?  I can think of a couple alternative approaches:

1. In the SO privilege help page on [voting down](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), include an explanation to "be careful voting down an answer to a very new question; here's why" and link to or paraphrase the aforementioned MSO explanations. - or -
2. When a downvote is cast within the grace period, show a dialog (with a "don't show this again" option) that warns the user with similar text.

The 2nd alternative may be overkill? But 1st seems innocuous enough.