# Upvote after downvote and after grace period has ended

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, grace-period

I understand that undoing a downvote after the grace-period is denied for strategic reasons (explained here: [Unable to undo downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote)).

But what if your downvote was just an accident which you did not notice right away? I'd like to make up for my bad vote and I do not care about the points.

Would it be possible to allow an upvote to compensate for the downvote but without regaining the reputation points spent for downvoting?

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusion. I was just talking about voting on answers.

Okay, the real reason for vote locking may be another than I assumed, but it does not matter for this discussion: What negative consequences are to be expected, if upvoting (for compensating accidentical, locked downvotes) was allowed? (The upvote would of course get locked, too.)

Comment: But what about questions? Downvoting them cost no rep.

Comment: That's one of the reasons to finish reading and understand the post carefully before voting... (I did some accidental votes too though). I could only suggest to (wait for/suggest an) edit the post and try to improve anything at all, then to re-vote accordingly.

Comment: "_undoing a downvote after the grace-period is denied for strategic reasons_" Many users think that votes are locked to prevent strategic downvoting, but actually that's not true. The real reasons for the votes being locked is explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291292/4284627) (not that I agree with it, but that's why the moderators decided that votes should be locked).

Comment: I think it would work. Although a little bit of random downs is known and so or so accepted by the community. And I think, if you really-really check any post, maybe you can find some way to improve it. After you improved it, you can change your vote.