# I should be able to undo my downvote if it the post was changed during the grace period

Tags: bug, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I change my vote if the  post has been edited during the initial 5mn grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-g)

I downvoted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770881/546661) when it only said

> You can fire a submit with the help of javascript.

and the answer improved significantly after he edited it, and I want to undo my downvote.

Unfortunately there is no record of him editing it because he fixed it within the 5 minute grace period, and so it won't let me undo my downvote.

I'm going to edit his post just so I can undo the downvote, but I think this should be fixed.

Comment: "Easy fix": don't be so fast to downvote.

Comment: @Mat I think it's a problem if we have to wait 5 minutes to downvote something. It's better to have immediate feedback if your answer is amiss.

Comment: I don't really agree with that. FGITW syndrome and all. Wait a bit & comment if the answer is incomplete but not incorrect.

Comment: @random If this is still happening, and the other one is `status-completed`, then why is this a duplicate? Isn't it a bug if something previously completed is now reoccuring?

Comment: Did you try and change the vote after the five minutes when you first voted?

Comment: @Mat FGITW is precisely the problem. Users post half-answers to be first and then edit them to fix them. There's nothing wrong with completing your answer and *then* posting it. In fact, that's probably better because users will *still* find things that need fixing and won't have to worry about going over the 5 minute grace period with all the extra editing, and they won't have to worry about early downvotes. FGITW is actually harmful to the answerer, because when I finally make my posts, I get to start at 0 while all the other cowboys have -1's and now have to scramble to catch up. :)