# Revert Downvote after Quick Edit

Tags: bug, down-votes, edits, grace-period

I have just downvoted a really bad one-line question. However the author then edited but because it was within the grace period and made good.

The problem is because it appears that the question hasn't been edited, I can't revert my down-vote.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: that's... not a problem

Comment: Well, it does punish OP for editing the question quickly; if they'd waited until a lot of people had the opportunity to waste their time reading the bad question or someone else had to take the time to do the edit, they'd get back their reputation; it seems like the system punishes desirable behavior.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. The system should pick up the grace period edit for the purpose of allowing the votes to be changed.

Comment: @Wooble, for me the *desirable* behavior is not to post crap in the first place. Too bad the one-line question poster had to learn the hard way, but hopefully they did learn.