# How often are posts indexed for searching?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

In [How does Stack Overflow implement its search indexing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187431/168244) it's mentioned that the post indexing cycle

> ... runs every 30 seconds on stackoverflow.com and here, 5 minutes for all other main sites, and 10 minutes for child metas.

On [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) the post [looking for Latex editor with good structure tree layout view that can handle verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152083/5764) (asked Jan 1, 2014) contains the word `TexMaker`:

[image]

However, [searching for questions containing `texmaker`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=texmaker%20is%3aquestion) yields the latest result from Dec 19th, 2013 (15 days ago):

[image]

Has the indexing procedure changed? Or what's going on here?

Related posts:

- [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/168244)
- [How frequently are new questions indexed by search engines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36925/168244)

Comment: That leaves us at the mercy of [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:tex.stackexchange.com+is:a+texmaker#q=site:tex.stackexchange.com+is:a+texmaker&tbs=qdr:d)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so those indexing times are correct, this was a different issue.  You may have noticed before the holidays that TeX was read-only for the better part of a day while I did some very fun database maintenance.  For some reason I can't explain (it predates me working for Stack), TeX and its meta (and *only* those) databases had a case insensitive collation.  Changing that is somewhat of a pain in the ass, hence the read-only mode for a while.

Doing that caused some other ripples with search that needed a fresh indexing pass (from scratch) to really fix.  That has just been performed.  It should operate correctly going forward.

Comment: Can't remember, was "It was like that when I got here!" Homer or Bart?