# How does Stack Exchange use Elasticsearch?

Tags: support, search, elasticsearch

I'd like to know how Stack Exchange is using ElasticSearch in practice (if it's not a secret):

- How did you organize the indexes? (based on types, on time, something else?)
- How many shards and replicas are used per index?
- How many nodes you have?
- How many documents are in one index?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange

Comment: Your full right to ask, but not sure you'll get an answer. Not really a secret but more like "not our business", literally. :)

Comment: and a related answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187501/158100

Comment: ShadowWizard: You're right I'm just looking for some real data. 
rene: I read both of those posts and thats why I asked :)

Comment: It really helps if you include your research in your question...