# Post does not show up immediately in search

Tags: support, search

Why does it take a while when I search a site for my own posts with the "user:me" keywords for my last post to the site to show up?

Comment: Caching, it is always caching.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I am not the expert, but don't new posts get pushed into the cache once created?

Comment: I don't know if it's related but it does take about 5 minutes for posts to appear on the front page for everyone... but that's by design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All search results are cached for a short amount of time so we don't have to run the query for that search every single time you look at those results or change the page.

Essentially:

- When you run a search, the system checks to see if there's already a recent cache for that exact same search. If so, it displays results from that cache.
- If there is no cache or it's too old and stale, it refreshes the cache with new results and displays from that.

Pretty much any list of questions you can possibly look at on our sites runs off of this same model of cached search results. There is no such thing as a completely live search.

Comment: I think the answer is not accurate, especially for sites other than Stack Overflow. As Nick says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187431/how-does-stack-overflow-implement-its-search-indexing/187501#187501), it takes 5 minutes on main sites other than SO and 10 minutes in per-site metas for the indexing process to run, while I'm pretty sure the search results cache is about one minute only.